# Leyland Numbers

Tags: code-golf, math, number, sequence, arithmetic

Given a natural number \$n\$, return the \$n\$-th [Leyland number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leyland_number).

#### Leyland Number

Leyland numbers are positive integers \$k\$ of the form

$$k = x^y + y^x$$

Where \$x\$ and \$y\$ are integers strictly greater than 1.

They are enumerated in ascending order.

**EDIT:** @DigitalTrauma suggested I include following "definition":

> Imagine we throw \$x^y+y^x\$ in a bag for all possible values of \$x\$ and \$y\$, and avoid throwing in duplicates. Then we sort that bag. The sorted bag is our sequence.

#### Details

You may use 0 or 1 based indexing, whatever suits you best.

Your program must be able to output at least all Leyland numbers less than the maximum of signed 32-bit integers. (The last Leyland number below this limit is `1996813914`, at index `82`.)

#### Test cases

The first few terms are following:

```
8, 17, 32, 54, 57, 100, 145, 177, 320, 368, 512, 593, 945, 1124
```

[A076980](https://oeis.org/A076980) in OEIS, except for the first entry. Note that because of that additional first entry, the indices on OEIS are shifted by one.

More can be found in the [OEIS b-file](https://oeis.org/A076980/b076980.txt)

Comment: `They are enumerated in ascending order` I'm not really sure what this means. Could you provide a list of x and y?

Comment: @DrGreenEggsandIronMan That means, `8` is before `17`, not the other way round.

Comment: @DrGreenEggsandIronMan I think it's `2^2+2^2=8`; `2^3+3^2=17`; `2^4+4^2=32`; `2^5+5^2=57`; `2^6+6^2=100`; `3^4+4^3=145` <- Note that `3^4+4^3` (=`145`) is lower than `2^7+7^2` (=`177`). So basically all possible combinations of `x^y+y^x` sorted from lowest to highest smaller than `1996813914`.

Comment: @DrGreenEggsandIronMan Imagine we throw `x^y+y^x` in a bag for all possible values of `x` and `y`, and avoid thrwoing in duplicates. Then we sort that bag. The sorted bag is our sequence.

Comment: Regarding the 2^32 requirement, does that apply to time or memory considerations? Is it acceptable if the program works I'm theory with unlimited time and memory?

Comment: No, it should work on your computer and terminate within a reasonable time.

Comment: @flawr [I think this comment](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/82981/leyland-numbers#comment202282_82981) makes it a lot clearer.  Can you edit this into the question?

Comment: Very large bag you have there

Comment: @LuisMendo Ask @​HenriLéonLebesgue and he is going to tell you that this bag is basically nothing.

Comment: @flawr Its contained volume is also probably in the neighborhood of -1/12.

Answer (score 11):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), <s>16</s> <s>15</s> 13 bytes

```
Q:Qt!^t!+uSG)
```

Output is 1-based.

[**Try it online!**](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=UTpRdCFedCErdVNHKQ&input=ODI)

#### Explanation

```
Q    % Take input n. Add 1
:Q   % Range [2 ... n+1]. This is enough to be used as x and y
t!   % Duplicate and transpose
^    % Power, element-wise with broadcast. Gives 2D, square array with x^y
     % for all pairs of x and y
t!   % Duplicate and transpose. Gives square array with y^x
+    % Add, element-wise
u    % Keep unique elements. This linearizes (flattens) the 2D array
S    % Sort
G)   % Get the n-th entry. Implicitly display
```

Comment: In Matlab `unique` sorts the elements. Doesn't it in MATL, too?

Comment: @pajonk MATL uses the `'stable'` flag for `unique` by default as that is the more typical usage.

Comment: @Suever Ok, thanks for clarifying.

Comment: I feel like we use the `t!^` (where `^` can be replaced by `+`, `-`, or any number of operators) motif a lot. What if we made `&` mean 1 input for some of those where for a vector it has that behavior?

Comment: @Suever That's a great idea! I've done some research with your script; see the chat

Answer (score 6):

## Java 10, <s>225</s> <s>221</s> <s>219</s> <s>216</s> <s>206</s> <s>204</s> <s>193</s> <s>192</s> <s>130</s> 129 bytes

```java
n->{var S=new java.util.TreeSet();for(int i=56,t;i<840;)S.add(Math.pow(i/28,t=i%28+2)+Math.pow(t,i++/28));return S.toArray()[n];}
```

0-indexed

-2 bytes (221 → 219) saved by replacing `1996813915` with `(1L<<31)` thanks to *@LeakyNun*.
-3 bytes (219 → 216) thanks to *@LeakyNun* and *@Frozn* with something I forgot myself..
-10 bytes (216 → 206) by changing Java 7 to 8.
-2 bytes (206 → 204) by replacing `ArrayList` with `Vector` thanks to *@TAsk*.
-11 bytes (204 → 193) by removing `s<(1L<<31)&`, since the question states "***at least** all Leyland numbers less than the maximum of signed 32-bit integers*".
-1 byte (193 → 192) by changing `Vector` to `Stack`.
-62 bytes (192 → 130) by switching to Java 10 and using `var`; removing the `Collection.sort`, `import java.util.*;`, if-statement and temp-long `s` by using a `java.util.TreeSet` (which is a set of unique values and sorts automatically); and using `Double` and `Object` return-type instead of `Long` so we can remove the `(int)(...)` cast and `<Long>`.
-1 byte (130 → 129) thanks to *@ceilingcat* by changing the two nested `[2,30]` loops to a single `[56,840]` loop.

[Try it here](https://tio.run/##PVDBbsIwDL3zFRbSpEQpgVVsqhY6aR8AO5Qb4hDasKWUNEpdEEJ8e@cWxiG2/Bz7@b1Sn/SkLA6db3eVzSGvdNPAUlt3HQFYhybsdW5g1ZcA37vS5Ag5ow44rgi8jSg0qJGmV@Aghc5NPq8nHSBLnTlDSRSyRVvJdTAmM8i42tdhWGHTt/cIlV0k85nimdRFwZYaf6Wvz8xO4yTC1L7EiYi5eOIYWSGox7kKBtvgIJNYf4WgL4xv3FbdOtUf9ZD0uO1U2wKOJIxlGKz72WxBc7jLmk5hbRrSVRcG6DbQFQmnT1C36FsEVtjGV/oyQM5E0Bys98/KYC75sKkfvisjI2aK0gJe530WKcT/fADZpUFzlLReeiLCyjErxh8wFk6Su3ywtje3f7fuDw)

**Explanation:**

```java
n->{                             // Method with integer parameter and Object return-type
  var S=new java.util.TreeSet(); //  Create a sorted Set, initially empty
  for(int i=56,t;i<840)          //  Loop `i` in the range [56,840]
    t.add(                       //   Add to the Set:
      Math.pow(i/28,             //    `i` integer-divided by 28
               t=i%28+2)         //    to the power `i` modulo-28 + 2
      +Math.pow(t,               //    And add `i` modulo-28 + 2
                i++/28));        //    to the power `i` integer-divided by 28
                                 //    (and increase `i` by 1 afterwards with `i++`)
  return S.toArray()             //  Convert the sorted Set to an Object-array
           [n];}                 //  And return the value at the input-integer index
```

Comment: 10/10 for using java

Comment: Since you only need to support up to `2^31-1` (i.e., signed int), can't you swap out a bunch of the `long` casts?

Comment: @TimmyD I don't think so, because they will overflow in the process.

Comment: @TimmyD Maybe, but then I need to know the exact range for both for-loops, and even then it probably overflows.. (Also, I was too lazy / 'busy' with work to determine that max myself and just used two times `25` and an `if(s<1996813915)` check. xD)

Comment: Quick golfs: `import java.util.*;long c(int n){List<Long>t=new ArrayList();for(int i=2,j;i<25;i++)for(j=2;j<25;j++){long s=(long)(Math.pow(i,j)+Math.pow(j,i));if(s<(1L<<31)&!t.contains(s))t.add(s);}Collections.sort(t);return t.get(n);}`

Comment: @LeakyNun You've only changed `if(s<1996813915&` to `if(s<(1L<<31)&` if I see that correctly? Or you also changed something else?

Comment: The for loop variable declaration.

Comment: @LeakyNun Ah of course.. Read past that (twice.. in my own code AND in your comment.. >.> ;p)

Comment: @LeakyNun According to [wolframalpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=25%5E25%2B25%5E25) `24^24+24^24 = 2667471553700568248898162945687552`, so I'd say it's more than enough for the `1996813915` maximum. :)

Comment: Have you put it in practice?

Comment: @LeakyNun Yes, [here is a (quick-and-dirty) ideone which outputs the entire list](https://ideone.com/rhoHeV).

Comment: @LeakyNun Even though `25^25+25^25` surpasses the max size of `long`, `Math.pow` returns `Integer.MAX_VALUE` when it's above a certain limit. Luckily for me, the max of this question is the same. :) [Math.pow source-code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/Math.java#Math.pow%28double%2Cdouble%29)

Comment: Yes, but it works not because `24^24+24^24` is very big. It works because you removed the bigger numbers. If you keep them there, it would not work.

Comment: @TimmyD Ah oops.. Changed to 30..

Comment: How about `for (int i = 1, j; ++i < 30;)` and `for (j = 1; ++j < 30;)`

Comment: @Frozn Thanks, edited. I always forget about that one for basic for-loops. Mostly because for-loops that use `someArray.length` it requires the `-1` to work without `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`, which is +1 bytes instead of -1.

Comment: [Largely beaten](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/83057/16236), after you beat me ;-)

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire I've beaten you again. ;p

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Good because my solution was clunky as hell! 

Comment: @ceilingcat Nice combination of the nested loops, thanks!

Answer (score 5):

### Haskell, 52 bytes

```haskell
r=[2..31]
([k|k<-[0..],elem k[x^y+y^x|x<-r,y<-r]]!!)
```

Really inefficient. Tests each natural number for being a Leyland number, making an infinite list of those that are. Given an input, takes that index element of the list. Uses that only `x,y` up to 31 need to be checked for 32 bit integers.

Same length with `filter`:

```haskell
r=[2..31]
(filter(`elem`[x^y+y^x|x<-r,y<-r])[0..]!!)
```

Comment: In hindsight such an obvious solution, I like it a lot!

Answer (score 4):

## Pyth, 17 bytes

0-indexed.

```
@{Sms^M_Bd^}2+2Q2
```

[Try it online!](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%40%7BSms%5EM_Bd%5E%7D2%2B2Q2&input=96&debug=0) (Please, keep it at 100.)

### How it works

```
@{Sms^M_Bd^}2+2Q2
@{Sms^M_Bd^}2+2Q2Q  implicit filling. Input:Q

           }2+2Q    Yield the array [2,3,4,...,Q+2]
          ^     2   Cartesian square: yield all the
                    pairs formed by the above array.
   m     d          Map the following to all of those pairs (e.g. [2,3]):
       _B               Create [[2,3],[3,2]]
     ^M                 Reduce by exponent to each array:
                        create [8,9]
    s                   Sum:   17     (Leyland number generated)
  S                 Sort the generated numbers
 {                  Remove duplicate
@                Q  Find the Q-th element.
```

### Slower version

1-indexed.

```
e.ffqZs^M_BT^}2Z2
```

[Try it online!](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=e.ffqZs%5EM_BT%5E%7D2Z2&input=3&debug=0) (Please, keep it at 3.)

Comment: Would it help to create an array of powers [[4,8,...][9,27,...]] and add it to its transpose?

Comment: @Neil I don't think so. It would be helpful in Jelly, but not in Pyth. Pyth does not automatically vectorize.

Comment: Also helps in MATL, it seems.

Comment: Why do you keep the slower version?

Answer (score 4):

## MATLAB, 58 bytes

1-indexed

```
n=input('');[A B]=ndgrid(2:n+9);k=A.^B;x=unique(k'+k);x(n)
```

`unique` in MATLAB flattens and sorts the matrix.

---

Thanks for help to [@FryAmTheEggman](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/31625/fryamtheeggman) and [@flawr](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/24877/flawr).

Answer (score 4):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), <sup><s>13</s></sup> 12 bytes

```
!uΞ´Ṫ§+^`^tN
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/X7H03LxDWx7uXHVouXZcQlyJ3////y2MAA)

<s>Tied with MATL, with a similar method.</s>

-1 byte from Zgarb!

### Explanation

```
!uΞ´Ṫ§+^`^tN
           N list of all natural numbers
          t  tail: remove 1
   ´         double: f x = f x x
    Ṫ        cartesian product with the following function
     §       fork: f g h x y = f (g x y) (h x y)
       ^     x^y
      +      plus
        `    reverse: f x y = f y x
        `^   y^x
  Ξ          merge all results together
 u           uniquify
!            take element at input index
```

Comment: The 12-byte code [`Q:Qt!^&+uSG)`](https://tio.run/#matl#code=UTpRdCFedCErdVNHKQ&input=ODI) would work in recent versions of MATL, but I prefer to keep the original code, which runs in versions predating the challenge :-)

Comment: @LuisMendo Husk hasn't been updated since around 2017, so I guess we're on an even playing field.

Answer (score 3):

### 05AB1E, <s>20</s> 19 bytes

0-indexed

```
ÝÌ2ãvyÂ`ms`m+}){Ù¹è
```

**Explained**

```
ÝÌ                     # range(2,N+2)
  2ã                   # get all pairs of numbers in the range
    v                  # for each pair
     yÂ`ms`m+          # push x^y+y^x
             }         # end loop
              ){Ù      # wrap to list, sort and remove duplicates
                 ¹è    # get Nth element of list
```

[Try it online](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=w53DjDLDo3Z5w4JgbXNgbSt9KXvDmcK5w6g&input=Nzc)

Saved 1 byte thanks to @Adnan

Comment: Very nice! One tip, `ÝÌ` is short for `>L>`.

Comment: @Adnan: Thanks! I can't belive I didn't think of that :P

Comment: `ê` is sorted_uniquified, if that existed when this was asked.

Comment: @carusocomputing: It was bugged until quite recently I'm afraid.

Comment: I know these builtins weren't available back then, but `2ã` can be `â`; `vy...})` can be `ε...}`; and `{Ù` can be `ê` for -4 bytes.

Answer (score 3):

## Mathematica, <s>60</s> <s>48</s> 40 bytes

```
(Union@@Array[#^#2+#2^#&,{#,#},2])[[#]]&
```

Uses one-based indexing. `Union` is used by applying it between each row of the 2D matrix created by the `Array`. There, `Union` will flatten the 2D matrix into a list while also removing any duplicates and placing the values in sorted order.

Saved 8 bytes thanks to @[LLlAMnYP](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/46206/lllamnyp).

### Usage

[image: Example]

Comment: `{#+1,#+1}` isn't necessary, can be left as `{#,#}` and `{2,2}` can be replaced with simply `2`.

Comment: @LLlAMnYP Thanks! Didn't know that `Array` would expand the third argument.

Comment: Neither did I but I decided to try it anyway and it worked :)

Answer (score 2):

### PowerShell v2+, <s>84</s> <s>73</s> 68 bytes

```
(2..30|%{2..($x=$_)|%{"$x*"*$_+'1+'+"$_*"*$x+1|iex}}|sort)[$args[0]]
```

*Saved 11 bytes thanks to @Neil ... saved additional 5 bytes by reorganizing how the `iex` expression is evaluated.*

Naïve method, we simply double-for loop from `x=2..30` and `y=2..x`. Each loop we put `x^y + y^x` on the pipeline. The `30` was chosen experimentally to ensure that we covered all cases less than `2^31-1` ;-). We pipe those to `Sort-Object` to order them ascending. Output is zero-indexed based on the input `$args[0]`.

Yes, there are a *lot* of extraneous entries generated here -- this algorithm actually generates 435 Leyland numbers -- but things above index `81` are not guaranteed to be accurate and in order (there may be some that are skipped).

#### Examples

```
PS C:\Tools\Scripts\golfing> .\leyland-numbers.ps1 54
14352282

PS C:\Tools\Scripts\golfing> .\leyland-numbers.ps1 33
178478

PS C:\Tools\Scripts\golfing> .\leyland-numbers.ps1 77
1073792449
```

Answer (score 2):

### JavaScript (Firefox 42-57), 94 bytes

```
n=>[for(x of Array(32).keys())for(y of Array(x+1).keys())if(y>1)x**y+y**x].sort((x,y)=>x-y)[n]
```

Needs Firefox 42 because it uses both array comprehensions and exponentiation (`[for(..of..)]` and `**`).

Comment: Shouldn't you just mark it as ES7?

Comment: @mbomb007 I don't think `[for...of]` made it to ES7.

Comment: [It's part of ES6](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-for-in-and-for-of-statements)

Comment: No, that's `for(..of..)`, not `[for(..of..)]`.

Comment: Ah, okay. [(Non-standard. Do not use.)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Array_comprehensions) lol

Comment: @mbomb007 Sure, but they're ideal for golfing: they combine both `map` and `filter`, they accept any iterable object, not just an array, and they support multiple loops that result in a single array.

Comment: In other words, just like any other comprehension (like Python)

Answer (score 2):

### Python 3, <s>76</s> 69 bytes

```
r=range(2,32);f=lambda n:sorted({x**y+y**x for x in r for y in r})[n]
```

0-indexed.

https://repl.it/C2SA

Comment: It’s okay to just write your answer as `r=range(2,32)` `lambda n:sorted(…)[n]`

Answer (score 2):

## Jelly, 14 bytes

2 bytes thanks to Dennis.

```
R‘*€¹$+Z$FṢQị@
```

[Try it online!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=UuKAmCrigqzCuSQrWiRG4bmiUeG7i0A&input=&args=OTc&debug=on) (Takes ~ 1s for 82 for me) (O(n^2) time)

#### Original 16-byte answer

```
2r30*€¹$+Z$FṢQị@
```

[Try it online!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=MnIzMCrigqzCuSQrWiRG4bmiUeG7i0A&input=&args=ODI) (Takes < 1s for me) (Constant time)

Comment: `R‘*€¹$+Z$FṢQị@` is faster, shorter and has no artificial upper bound.

Comment: @Dennis and beats my answer :-P

Comment: @Dennis I don't get it. How come it is faster than the second one.

Comment: It isn't faster than the second one. The execution time is too short to get an accurate measurement.

Comment: Now 13 bytes :-P

Answer (score 2):

## Bash + GNU utilities, 63

```bash
printf %s\\n x={2..32}\;y={2..32}\;x^y+y^x|bc|sort -nu|sed $1!d
```

1-based indexing.  It looks like this is pretty much the same approach as [@TimmyD's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/82986/11259).  Instead of nested loops, bash brace expansion is used to generate arithmetic expressions that are piped to `bc` for evaluation.

[Ideone.](https://ideone.com/4CvMCI)

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 6](http://perl6.org),  <s>60 58</s>  56 bytes

```perl6
{sort(keys bag [X[&({$^a**$^b+$b**$a})]] (2..$_+2)xx 2)[$_]}
{sort(keys set [X[&({$^a**$^b+$b**$a})]] (2..$_+2)xx 2)[$_]}
{sort(unique [X[&({$^a**$^b+$b**$a})]] (2..$_+2)xx 2)[$_]}
{squish(sort [X[&({$^a**$^b+$b**$a})]] (2..$_+2)xx 2)[$_]}
{squish(sort [X[&({$^a**$^b+$b**$a})]] (2..31)xx 2)[$_]}
{squish(sort [X[&({$^a**$^b+$b**$a})]] 2..31,2..31)[$_]}
```

#### Test:

```perl6
#! /usr/bin/env perl6
use v6.c;

my &Leyland = {squish(sort [X[&({$^a**$^b+$b**$a})]] 2..31,2..31)[$_]}

say ^14 .map: &Leyland;
time-this {Leyland 81};

sub time-this (&code) {
  my $start = now;
  my $value = code();
  printf "takes %.3f seconds to come up with $value\n", now - $start;
}
```

```
(8 17 32 54 57 100 145 177 320 368 512 593 945 1124)
takes 0.107 seconds to come up with 1996813914
```

#### Explanation:

```perl6
{
  squish( # remove repeated values
    sort
      [X[&( # cross reduce with:
        { $^a ** $^b + $b ** $a }
      )]]
        ( 2 .. $_+2 ) # ｢Range.new(2,$_+2)｣ (inclusive range)
        xx 2          # repeat list
  )[$_]
}
```

Comment: Can't you remove the spaces between `sort [` and `] 2..31`?

Comment: @EʀɪᴋᴛʜᴇGᴏʟғᴇʀ That would turn it from a subroutine call `sort([...` to an array access of a term `sort[...`. A similar thing happens with the other space.

Comment: I guess there you have implemented this half-pseudo code `map { $^a ** $^b + $b ** $a },  2..5,5...2`
But, how could you think of constructing it that way at the first place? The cross reduce with a closure is particularly tricky. Could you give some sample invocations of that closure?

Comment: @LarsMalmsteen There are a lot of things working together there. I don't think that this is a good place to discuss this. If you post your questions to the `perl6-users` mailing list, I and everyone else on there would be more than happy to help you understand. I think the reason I used reduce `[]` was to reduce the number of spaces and parens.

Comment: Shave another 2 chars: `say {squish(sort 2..31 X[&({$^a**$^b+$b**$a})]2..31)[$_]}`

Answer (score 2):

## F#, <s>117</s>, 104

Welp, it's shorter than my C# answer at least.

Saved 13 bytes thanks to Reed Copsey in the F# chatroom.

```
let f n=[for x in 2I..32I do for y in 2I..32I->x**(int y)+y**(int x)]|>Seq.sort|>Seq.distinct|>Seq.nth n
```

Answer (score 2):

## R, <s>58</s> 54 bytes

1-indexed. Eliminated 4 bytes by using `pryr::r` instead of `function`.

```
unique(sort(outer(2:99,2:9,pryr::f(x^y+y^x))))[scan()]
```

#### Explanation

For all numbers from 2 to 99, and 2 to 9,

```
                  2:99,2:9
```

apply the function `x^y+y^x`. This generates a 98x8 matrix.

```
            outer(2:99,2:9,pryr::f(x^y+y^x))
```

Sort this matrix (coercing it to a vector):

```
       sort(outer(2:99,2:9,pryr::f(x^y+y^x)))
```

Remove all non-unique values:

```
unique(sort(outer(2:99,2:9,pryr::f(x^y+y^x))))
```

Read `n` from stdin, and fetch the `n`th number from the list:

```
unique(sort(outer(2:99,2:9,pryr::f(x^y+y^x))))[scan()]
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 12 bytes

```
‘€p`*U$§QṢị@
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9Rw4xHTWsKErRCVQ4tD3y4c9HD3d0O/w1NrA@3qwAl3P8DAA)

Similar algorithm to [Leaky Nun](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/48934/leaky-nun)'s [Jelly answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/82998/66833) but with a few improvements

### How it works

```
‘€p`*U$§QṢị@ - Main link. Takes n on the left
 €           - Yield [1, 2, ..., n]
‘            - Increment each to [2, 3, ..., n+1]
  p`         - Take the Cartesian product with itself, yielding all pairs [[2, 2], [2, 3], ..., [n+1, n+1]]
      $      - Run the previous two commands over each pair, [x, y]:
     U       -   Reverse the pair to yield [y, x]
    *        -   Raise to the power to yield [x*y, y*x]
       §     - Take the sum of each, yielding [8, 17, ..., 2(n+1)*(n+1)]]
        Q    - Deduplicate
         Ṣ   - Sort in ascending order
          ị@ - Take the nth element in this list
```

Answer (score 1):

## Haskell, <s>99</s> <s>98</s> <s>96</s> <s>95</s> 94 bytes

It is probably easily outgolfed, but that was the best *I* was able to come up with.

```
import Data.List
f n|n<2=[]|n>1=sort.nub$f(n-1)++[x^n+n^x|x<-[2..n]]
g n=(f.toInteger$n+3)!!n
```

Comment: import Data.List
f n|w<-[2..toEnum$n+3]=(sort$nub[x^y+y^x|x<-w,y<-w])!!n
Do you know why toInteger/toEnum is needed?

Comment: Wow, this is crazy=) Feel free to add it as your own answer, as it is qutie different from mine! If we omit `toInteger` in my solution we'll have an overflow using `int`, because we iterate way higher (to `n+3` instead of `n`) when working with the list. Otherwise we'd need to hardcode the first four terms or so. What exactly does `toEnum` do in your solution?

Comment: OK, that's because of (!!) operator which binds n to an Int. Since n is supposed to be under 82, w can be replaced by [2..99] for example and `f=(sort(nub[x^y+y^x|x<-[2..99],y<-[2..x]])!!)` .  `toEnum` converts an Int to an Enum, and Integer is an instance of Enum class so toEnum here converts n+3 to an Integer.

Answer (score 1):

## C#, <s>141</s>, 127 bytes.

Oh c#, you are such a long language.

```
n=>(from x in Enumerable.Range(2,32)from y in Enumerable.Range(2,32)select Math.Pow(x,y)+Math.Pow(y,x)).Distinct().ToList()[n];
```

This is a lambda that needs to be assigned to `delegate double del(int n);` to be run, as such:

```
delegate double del(int n);
del f=n=>(from x in Enumerable.Range(2,32)from y in Enumerable.Range(2,32)select Math.Pow(x,y)+Math.Pow(y,x)).OrderBy(q=>q).Distinct().ToList()[n];
```

Comment: Still shorter than [Java](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/82992/24877).

Comment: @flawr Wooooooo?

Comment: I know nothing about C#, but couldn't you save `Enumerable.Range(` to a variable/function/iterator/whatever with a shorter name for reuisng?

Comment: I could, but then I would need to include a class and type defs, which ends up costing me a ton.

Answer (score 1):

## SQL (PostgreSQL 9.4), 171 bytes

Done as a prepared statement.  Generate a couple of series 2 - 99, cross join them and do the equation.  Densely rank the results to index them and select the first result that has the rank of the integer input.

```
prepare l(int)as select s from(select dense_rank()over(order by s)r,s from(select x^y+y^x from generate_series(2,99)x(x),generate_series(2,99)y(y))c(s))d where r=$1limit 1
```

Executed as follows

```
execute l(82)
s
-----------------
1996813914
```

This ended up running a lot quicker than I expected

Answer (score 1):

## Swift 3, 138 bytes

```
import Glibc;func l(n:Int)->Int{let r=stride(from:2.0,to:50,by:1);return Int(Set(r.flatMap{x in r.map{pow(x,$0)+pow($0,x)}}).sorted()[n])}
```

**Ungolfed code**

[Try it here](http://swiftlang.ng.bluemix.net/#/repl/57626383047269a43fc085c0)

```
import Glibc
func l(n: Int) -> Int {
    // Create a Double sequence from 2 to 50 (because pow requires Double)
    let r = stride(from: 2.0, to: 50.0, by: 1.0)

    return Int(Set(r.flatMap {
        x in r.map {
            pow(x, $0) + pow($0, x)
        }
    }).sorted()[n])
```

Comment: Welcome to Programming Puzzles and Code Golf! Nice first answer, but it'd be better if you could explain what's going on.

Answer (score 1):

## [Java (JDK)](http://jdk.java.net/), 136 bytes

```java
n->java.util.stream.IntStream.range(0,900).map(l->l+=Math.pow(l%30+2,l/30+2)+Math.pow(l/30+2,l%30+2)-l).sorted().distinct().toArray()[n]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RVA9b8IwEN37K05IkWwlcSJY2lKQOnaAhW6IwY0NNTi2FV@oUMVvT8@BtoPv4/m@3jvKsyyP6jSE/sOaBhorY4SVNO77AcA41N1eNhrWKR0BaFiyjs8JuT6QiSiRWtfgYAGDK5dHGip6NFZE7LRsxZvDzS3qpDtoVhdPdc1FKwOz5dLmi5XETxH8F7PZrM6nha2S4/k/Xt3w8ZuXlovoO9SKcaFMROMapBD9a9fJC@Nbtxvm6bY7rfuJZ28UtESO0TnGHbY7kBxu1KoK3nUkel5p2PsOpCXyVAS@x9AjMFoUrLyMkNMFxJMJ4S/T2Ag@TkrNo0aG9Kjn5F7gcUo@z3@XAWwuEXUraLYItAX3bJLN1DNkKnOTAkwBTpDSfJQ5CZ3edfgB)

Comment: If you start the range at `60` then `l/30+2` can be `l/30`

Answer (score 1):

## J, 29 bytes

```
<:{[:/:~@~.@,[:(^+^~)"0/~2+i.
```

Uses one-based indexing. Conversion from my Mathematica [solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/83058/6710).

The true secret here is that I have `:(^+^~)` on my side.

### Usage

```
   f =: <:{[:/:~@~.@,[:(^+^~)"0/~2+i.
   f 7
145
   (,.f"0) >: i. 10  NB. Extra commands for formatting
 1   8
 2  17
 3  32
 4  54
 5  57
 6 100
 7 145
 8 177
 9 320
10 368
```

### Explanation

```
<:{[:/:~@~.@,[:(^+^~)"0/~2+i.  Input: n
                         2+i.  Step one
                     "0/~      Step two
              :(^+^~)          ???
<:{[:/:~@~.@,[                 Profit
```

More seriously,

```
<:{[:/:~@~.@,[:(^+^~)"0/~2+i.  Input: n
                           i.  Create the range [0, 1, ..., n-1]
                         2+    Add 2 to each
               (^+^~)"0        Create a dyad (2 argument function) with inputs x, y
                               and returns x^y + y^x
             [:        /~      Use that function to create a table using the previous range
   [:       ,                  Flatten the table into a list
         ~.@                   Take its distinct values only
     /:~@                      Sort it in ascending order
<:                             Decrement n (since J is zero-indexed)
  {                            Select the value at index n-1 from the list and return
```

Comment: *... Profit*  :D

Answer (score 1):

**Axiom 148 bytes**

```
w(n)==(v:List INT:=[];for i in 2..31 repeat for j in i..31 repeat(a:=i^j+j^i;if a>1996813914 then break;v:=cons(a,v));v:=sort v;~index?(n,v)=>0;v.n)
```

some example

```
w(n)==
 v:List INT:=[];for i in 2..31 repeat for j in i..31 repeat
        (a:=i^j+j^i;if a>1996813914 then break;v:=cons(a,v));v:=sort v;~index?(n,v)=>0
 v.n
 (2) -> [w(i)  for i in 0..85]
    Compiling function w with type NonNegativeInteger -> Integer

    (2)
    [0, 8, 17, 32, 54, 57, 100, 145, 177, 320, 368, 512, 593, 945, 1124, 1649,
     2169, 2530, 4240, 5392, 6250, 7073, 8361, 16580, 18785, 20412, 23401,
     32993, 60049, 65792, 69632, 93312, 94932, 131361, 178478, 262468, 268705,
     397585, 423393, 524649, 533169, 1048976, 1058576, 1596520, 1647086,
     1941760, 2012174, 2097593, 4194788, 4208945, 4785713, 7861953, 8389137,
     9865625, 10609137, 14352282, 16777792, 16797952, 33554432, 33555057,
     43050817, 45136576, 48989176, 61466176, 67109540, 67137425, 129145076,
     134218457, 177264449, 244389457, 268436240, 268473872, 292475249,
     364568617, 387426321, 536871753, 774840978, 1073742724, 1073792449,
     1162268326, 1173741824, 1221074418, 1996813914, 0, 0, 0]
```

### Type: List Integer

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 70 + 1 (-p) = 71 bytes

```perl
for$x(2..32){$r{$x**$_+$_**$x}++for$x..32}$_=(sort{$a<=>$b}keys%r)[$_]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/z8tv0ilQsNIT8/YSLNapahapUJLSyVeWyUeSFXUamuD5UGytSrxthrF@UUl1SqJNrZ2Kkm12amVxapFmtEq8bH//xv/yy8oyczPK/6v62uqZ2Bo8F@3AAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 28 bytes

```
^₂g{∧{Ċ≥₁>ᵛ1&≜↔;?^ᵐ+}}ᶠ⁽o∋↙?
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AUYAuf9icmFjaHlsb2cy//9e4oKCZ3viiKd7xIriiaXigoE@4bWbMSbiiZzihpQ7P17htZArfX3htqDigb1v4oiL4oaZP///N/9a)

#### How it works

```
^₂g{∧{Ċ≥₁>ᵛ1&≜↔;?^ᵐ+}}ᶠ⁽o∋↙?
^₂g                           7 -> [49]
   {∧{              }}ᶠ⁽      find first 49 outputs whose …
      Ċ≥₁>ᵛ1                  inputs are of form [X,Y],
       ≥₁                     are ordered
         >ᵛ1                  and strictly greater than 1
            &≜                force labels on input
              ↔;?             [2,3] -> [[3,2],[2,3]]
                 ^ᵐ                 -> [9, 8]
                   +                -> 17
                        o∋↙?  order outputs and take the Nth element
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2), 12 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
R⁺2ẉıḲ*S;ṠUi
```

[Try it online!](https://Not-Thonnu.github.io/run#aGVhZGVyPSZjb2RlPVIlRTIlODElQkEyJUUxJUJBJTg5JUM0JUIxJUUxJUI4JUIyKlMlM0IlRTElQjklQTBVaSZmb290ZXI9JmlucHV0PTUmZmxhZ3M9)

0-indexed.

##### Explanation

```python
R⁺2ẉıḲ*S;ṠUi  # Implicit input
R⁺            # Range [2..input+1]
  2ẉ          # Cartesian power of 2
    ı   ;     # Map over each pair:
     Ḳ        #  Bifurcate: push reverse
      *       #  Exponentiation
       S      #  Sum the pair
         Ṡ    # Sort the list
          U   # And uniquify it
           i  # Index in
              # Implicit output
```

Answer (score 0):

## J, <s>38</s> 31 bytes

0-indexed.

```
[{[:(#~~:)@/:~@,/[:(+|:)[:^/~2+i.@>:@]
((#~~:)/:~,/(+|:)^/~2+i.29x){~[
```

### Usage

```
>> f =: ((#~~:)/:~,/(+|:)^/~2+i.29x){~[
>> f 81
<< 1996813914
```

Answer (score 0):

## Python 3, 129->116 bytes

I know there is a shorter python 3 answer, but I still wanted to contribute my solution.

```python
t=[]
for k in range(100):a,b,q=k//10,k%10,a**b+b**a;f=lambda q:0if q in t else t.append(q);f(q)
print(sorted(t)[7:])
```

This was the best way that I could to think of to handle going through all values for x and all values for y.
If anyone can golf my approach it would be appreciated

Comment: Make `t` a [`set`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset) instead of a list, and replace the last `for` statements with a plain `t.add(q)`.

Answer (score 0):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), <s>62</s> 58 bytes

```ruby
->n{a,*b=c=2;c+=1while(b<<a**c+c**a;c<32||32>c=a+=1);b[n]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf1y6vOlFHK8k22dbIOlnb1rA8IzMnVSPJxiZRSytZO1lLK9E62cbYqKbG2Mgu2TYRqELTOik6L7b2f4FCWrRBLBeIMoJQhqax/wE)

Comment: This seems to be missing a number of entries, the first of which is `54`

Answer (score 0):

## [APL (Dyalog)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 27 bytes

```apl
{d⊃⍨⍵⊃⍋d←∪,∘.(*⍨+*)⍨1↓⍳1+⍵}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///P@1R24TqlEddzY96Vzzq3QpmdKcABR91rNJ51DFDT0MLKKOtpQkkDR@1TX7Uu9lQG6iwFqhV4RBQy2YFQwMA)

Answer (score 0):

## Japt `-g`, 15 bytes

```
g2ôU ïÈ**Y+pXÃü
```

[Try it](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.6&code=ZzL0VSDvyCoqWStwWMP8&input=OAotZw==)

```
g2ôU ïÈ**Y+pXÃü
                    :Implicit input of integer U
g                   :Index into the following array
 2ôU                :  Range [2,U+2]
     ï              :  Cartesian product with itself
      È             :  Reduce each pair [X,Y]
       **Y          :    Raise X to the power of Y
          +pX       :    Add Y raised to the power of X
             Ã      :  End reduce
              ü     :  Sort & partition by value
                    :Implicit output of first element
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 77 [bits<sup>v2</sup>](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyncode/blob/main/README.md), 9.625 bytes

```
›Ḣ:Ẋ:ReṠUsi
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=2#WyI9IiwiIiwi4oC64biiOuG6ijpSZeG5oFVzaSIsIiIsIjgxIl0=)

When the program is `ṠUs`.

0 indexed.

### Explained

```
›Ḣ:Ẋ:ReṠUsi­⁡​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁢⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁣​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁤⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁤​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁣⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌­
›Ḣ:Ẋ         # ‎⁡Cartesian product of the range [2, input + 1]
    :R       # ‎⁢Push a copy with each pair reversed. 
      eṠ     # ‎⁣Zip the two lists, reduce by a ** b, and sum each pair. 
        Usi  # ‎⁤Uniquify, sort, then get the number at the inputh index.
```

Created with the help of [Luminespire](https://vyxal.github.io/Luminespire).