# Now I know my ABCs, won't you come and golf with me?

Tags: code-golf, string, kolmogorov-complexity

Write a program or function that outputs this exact text, case-insensitive:

```
A, B, C, D, E, F, G,
H, I, J, K, L, M, N, O, P,
Q, R, S,
T, U, V,
W, X, Y, Z.
```

(Based on the [alphabet song](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alphabet_song#The_A.B.C._.28Verse_1.29) that many American kids learn to help memorize the alphabet, though edited for more compressibility.)

The output must *look* exactly the same as the above (again, case-insensitive), but may contain trailing spaces on each line and/or trailing newlines. Notice the period at the end.

This is code-golf, so **the shortest code in bytes wins.**

Comment: For regex based languages consider a 0 width lookahead... `/(?=[HQTW])/`

Comment: I thought it was `H, I, J, K, LMNO, P`?

Comment: Shouldn't the last line end with "Y and Z."?

Comment: @KM. This was discussed in the [sandbox](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/2140/42545), and we decided to stick with this version to make the challenge less complicated.

Comment: Golf seems boring. Cricket is better.

Answer (score 18):

## Vim, <s>42</s>, 40 keystrokes/bytes

```
:h<_<cr>jjYZZP:s/./&, /g<cr>7f r<cr>9;.3;.3;.$ch.
```

Thanks to [Lynn and her awesome vim answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/87010/31716) for the tip to grab the alphabet from help.

Thanks to RomanGräf for saving two bytes!

Explanation:

```
:h<_<cr>                                      " Open up vim-help
        jj                                    " Move down two lines
          Y                                   " Yank this line (containing the alphabet)
           ZZ                                 " Close this buffer
             P                                " Paste the line we just yanked
              :s/./&, /g<cr>                  " Replace every character with that character followed by a comma and a space
                            7f                " Find the seven space on this line
                               r<cr>          " And replace it with a newline
                                    9;        " Repeat the last search (space) 9 times
                                      .       " Repeat the last edit (replace with a newline)
                                       3;     " Third space
                                         .    " Replace with newline
                                          3;  " Third space
                                            . " Replace with newline
```

Then, we move the end of the of the line with `$`, change back a character with `ch` and insert a dot.

Comment: You mustn't convert to uppercase. The OP said " this exact text, case-insensitive".

Comment: @RomanGräf Thanks for the tip!

Comment: Ha! Getting the alphabet from vim help is genius! Did you know that or did you look it up for this challenge?

Comment: @christianRondeau I did not come up with it. Lynn did in [this answer](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/86986/print-a-tabula-recta/87010#87010)

Comment: @RomanGräf +1 for using mustn't

Comment: I would finish with `$xr.` instead of `$ch.` so that I don't need to include `ESC` to exit insert mode.

Comment: @MartinKealey I'm not including the final esc.

Comment: I can plainly see that _you're_ not including `ESC`, which is fair game under the rules, but if _I_ was typing it I would feel obliged to include `ESC` so as to return to the same mode as when I began; hence my preference to use `$xr.` instead.

Answer (score 13):

## Bash + GNU utilities, 36

- 5 bytes saved thanks to Neil.

```bash
echo {A..Y}, Z.|sed 's/[HQTW]/\n&/g'
```

[Ideone.](https://ideone.com/6YcyW7)

Comment: Why not just `echo {A..Y}, Z.|sed 's/[HQTW]/\n&/g'` ?

Comment: @Neil Ooh very good!  thanks!

Answer (score 13):

## [05AB1E](http://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 16 bytes

**Code**

```
A',â79334S£»¨'.J
```

**Explanation:**

```
A                  # Push the alphabet.
 ',â               # Cartesian product with ','.
    79334S         # Push [7, 9, 3, 3, 4].
          £        # Contigious substring, pushes the substrings [0:7], [7:7+9], 
                     [7+9:7+9+3], [7+9+3:7+9+3+3], [7+9+3+3:7+9+3+3+4].
           »       # Gridify, join the inner arrays with spaces and join those arrays
                     with newlines.
            ¨      # Remove the last character.
             '.J   # Append a '.'-character.
```

Uses the **CP-1252** encoding. [Try it online!](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=QScsw6I3OTMzNFPCo8K7wqgnLko&input=)

Answer (score 12):

## JavaScript (ES6), <s>66</s> 65 bytes

Beating [@Neil](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/95006/42545) was impossible... That's why I did it. :-)

```
f=(i=10)=>i>34?"z.":i.toString(++i)+","+` 
`[9568512>>i-9&1]+f(i)
```

Golfed 1 byte thanks to a trick from [@LevelRiverSt](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/95044/42545). Using `String.fromCharCode` is 7 bytes longer:

```
f=(i=65)=>i>89?"Z.":String.fromCharCode(i,44,i%86%83%80%71?32:10)+f(i+1)
```

#### How it works

This recursively generates each character of the alphabet from `a` to `y`, using `.toString()`. A comma is appended after each letter, plus a newline if `9568512>>i-9&1` is 1, or a space otherwise. When the recursion gets past 34, i.e. to `z`, the function simply returns `"z."`.

Answer (score 10):

## Python 2.7, <s>67 66</s> 63 bytes

```python
a=65;exec"print'%c'%a+',.'[a>89]+'\\n'[a%42%39%9^2:],;a+=1;"*26
```

Dennis saved a byte.

Comment: Using `exec` instead of `for` should save a byte.

Answer (score 8):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>19</s> 18 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
ØAp”,ṁ79334DR¤GṖ”.
```

*Thanks to @Adnan for golfing off 1 byte!*

[Try it online!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=w5hBcOKAnSzhuYE3OTMzNERSwqRH4bmW4oCdLg&input=)

#### How it works

```
ØAp”,ṁ79334DR¤GṖ”.  Main link. No arguments.

ØA                  Yield "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ".
  p”,               Cartesian product with ','; append a comma to each letter.
             ¤      Combine the two links to the left into a niladic chain.
      79334D          Decimal; yield [7, 9, 3, 3, 4].
            R         Range; yield [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], ..., [1, 2, 3, 4]].
     ṁ              Mold; reshape the array of letters with commata like the
                    generated 2D array.
              G     Grid; separate rows by spaces, columns by linefeeds.
               Ṗ    Pop; discard the last comma.
                ”.  Print the previous result and set the return value to '.'.
                     (implicit) Print the return value.
```

Comment: 31 seconds? Dang...

Answer (score 6):

### Pyke, <s>23</s> <s>19</s> 17 bytes

```
G\,J\.+2cu  /P
```

[Try it here!](http://pyke.catbus.co.uk/?code=G%5C%2CJ%5C.%2B2cu%04%07%09%03%03%2FP)

```
G\,J\.+        -    ",".join(alphabet)+"."
       2c      -   split(^, size=2)
            /  -  split_sized(^, V)
         u     -   yield list [7,9,3,3] (actual bytes `u%04%07%09%03%03`)
             P - print(^)
```

Answer (score 6):

### Brainfuck, 117 bytes

```
+[++[-<]-[->->]<]+++[->++>+++>+>+<<<<<--<<->>>]>+[[-<<<<<+.>-.+>.>>>]>[[-<+>]>]<<[<]<.>>]<<-[---<<<+.>-.+>.>]<<<+.>+.
```

The first four lines each have a trailing space, and the program assumes 8-bit cells. [Try it online!](http://brainfuck.tryitonline.net/#code=K1srK1stPF0tWy0-LT5dPF0rKytbLT4rKz4rKys-Kz4rPDw8PDwtLTw8LT4-Pl0-K1tbLTw8PDw8Ky4-LS4rPi4-Pj5dPltbLTwrPl0-XTw8WzxdPC4-Pl08PC1bLS0tPDw8Ky4-LS4rPi4-XTw8PCsuPisu&input=)

<sup>(Handling the last line is tricky...)</sup>

Answer (score 6):

## Vim, 32 bytes

`26o<C-V><C-V>64,<Esc>r.V{g<C-A>8Jj9Jj3Jj.j4JcH<C-R>"`

Leaves a blank line at the end, which was allowed, but it's weird being this clumsy. Even worse, I'm ending in insert mode. I've seen some other folks do it here, so I guess it's allowed? It feels dirty.

- `26o<C-V><C-V>64,<Esc>`: The first `<C-V>` makes the second one insert literally. The `<C-V>64`s this leaves in the buffer will be turned into ASCII code points, then into letters. Commas already in.
- `r.`: Never going to be at the end again, so do the `.` now.
- `V{g<C-A>`: Uses visual increment to turn all the `64`s into the ASCII code points of the capital letters.
- `8Jj9Jj3Jj.j4J`: The arbitrary line joins. First one is `8J` instead of `7J` because we're dealing with the blank line. The repeated `3J`s are eligible for a dot repeat.
- `cH<C-R>"`: People usually think of `i<C-R>` as an insert mode paste, but it's more like an insert mode macro. Stuff like `<C-V>65` will run as if typed, and interpreted as a decimal code point. This leaves an extra (allowed) line at the end, and stays in insert mode.

Comment: if you have an issue with a policy (or a lack thereof), take it up on meta, not in an answer.

Answer (score 5):

### JavaScript (ES6), <s>80</s> 74 bytes

```
_=>[...`ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ`].join`, `.replace(/[HQTW]/g,`
$&`)+`.`
```

Probably possible to shorten this with atob/btoa if you can work out how to use ISO-8859-1 encoding. Edit: Saved 6 bytes thanks to @RickHitchcock.

Comment: @RickHitchcock Yes, I just realised that myself after reading the PHP answer.

Comment: @RickHitchcock You wanted `.join\`, \``? Put backslashes before the backticks. (Yes, comment markdown is different, sigh...)

Answer (score 5):

### Perl, 37 bytes

*Credits to [@Dom Hastings](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/9365/dom-hastings) for this solution (3 bytes shorter than mine, see bellow).*

```pl
say+(map"$_, ".$/x/[GPSV]/,A..Y),"Z."
```

Run with `-E` (or `-M5.010`) flag :

```
perl -E 'say+(map"$_, ".$/x/[GPSV]/,A..Y),"Z."'
```

My previous version, 3 bytes longer (total of 40 bytes) :

```
perl -E '$_=join", ",A..Z;s/[HQTW]/\n$&/g;say"$_."'
```

Comment: Slightly different approach (still uses the regex...) for 37 bytes: `say+(map"$_, ".$/x/[GPSV]/,A..Y),"Z."`

Comment: @DomHastings Nice one, Well done. And it's more beautiful to have one statement instead of three! ;-)

Answer (score 5):

## R, <s>83</s> 71 bytes

```r
a=rbind(LETTERS[-26],","," ");a[3,7+3*c(0,3:5)]="\n";cat(a,"Z.",sep="")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/P9G2KCkzL0XDxzUkxDUoOFrXyCxWRwkEFZQ0rROjjXXMtY21kjUMdIytTDVjbZVi8pSskxNLNBJ1lKL0lHSKUwtslZQ0//8HAA)

Makes a matrix of 3 rows (one with the letters, one with the commas and the other with either a space or a newline).

**Edit**: Thanks Billywob!

Comment: `cat(a,sep="")` saves a few bytes: `a=rbind(LETTERS,","," ");a[3,7+3*c(0,3:5)]="\n";cat(a[,-26],"Z.",sep="")`

Comment: Thanks! That helped a lot! Using the `[-26]` on `LETTERS` directly saves yet another byte.

Answer (score 5):

### CJam, 26 bytes

```
'A79333Ab{{',S2$)}*N\}/'.@
```

[Online interpreter](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code='A79333Ab%7B%7B'%2CS2%24%29%7D*N%5C%7D%2F'.%40)

```
'A                             Push 'A'
  79333Ab                      Push [7 9 3 3 3]
         {           }/        For each number n in the previous array...
          {      }*              Execute n times...
           ',S                     Push a comma and a space
              2$)                  Copy last letter and increment
                   N\            Place a newline under the letter on top
                       '.@     Push '.' and rotate
```

Answer (score 4):

## Brainfuck, 157 bytes

```
+++++[>+>+++<<-]>>[->+>++++>+++>++<<<<]>----->+++++.>-.>++.<<<<<+[->>>+.>.>.<<<<<]+++++++++>>.<<[->>>+.>.>.<<<<<]<---[+>+++>>.<<[->>>+.>.>.<<<<<]<]>>>>+.>++.
```

[Try it online](http://brainfuck.tryitonline.net/#code=KysrKytbPis-KysrPDwtXT4-Wy0-Kz4rKysrPisrKz4rKzw8PDxdPi0tLS0tPisrKysrLj4tLj4rKy48PDw8PCtbLT4-PisuPi4-Ljw8PDw8XSsrKysrKysrKz4-Ljw8Wy0-Pj4rLj4uPi48PDw8PF08LS0tWys-KysrPj4uPDxbLT4-PisuPi4-Ljw8PDw8XTxdPj4-PisuPisrLg&input=)

Answer (score 4):

## JavaScript (ES6), <s>66</s> <s>64</s> 60 bytes

```
_=>`ABCDEFG
HIJKLMNOP
QRS
TUV
WXY`.replace(/./g,"$&, ")+"Z."
```

Regex matches the characters but not the carriage returns, so, using regex replace, I can add the ", " to each character.

Edit: Removed 2 characters thanks to ETHProductions

Edit: Changed from CRLF to LF, thanks @Olivier Grégoire

Comment: I have no idea why the other JS golfers didn't go for this solution first. Here, have an upvote.

Comment: Dang, nice one! I think you can remove the parens in the regex if you change `$1` to `$&`.

Comment: I disagree with your byte count: you seem to count bytes as if a line is `\r\n`. But if you use `\n` only, you can shave 4 bytes off your count. So your bytecount is not 64, but 60, without changing anything in your code.

Comment: Thank you.   I changed line endings locally and tested, just to be certain, and updated the  count

Answer (score 4):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 15 bytes

```
n\,Ẋ7933fẇ⁋Ṫ\.+
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=2#WyIiLCIiLCJuXFws4bqKNzkzM2bhuofigYvhuapcXC4rIiwiIiwiIl0=) -2 thanks to lyxal. -1 thanks to ffseq

```
n               # Uppercase alphabet
   Ẋ            # Each prepended to
 \,             # ","
         ẇ      # Cut into chunks of lengths
    7933f       # Digits of 7933 (+ rest, which is 4)
          ⁋     # Join by newlines
           Ṫ    # Remove the last character
            \.+ # Append a dot
```

Comment: 27 bytes: [Try it Online!](https://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=kAf%60%2C%20%60j21%C2%B6%E1%B9%8049%C2%B6%E1%B9%8059%C2%B6%E1%B9%8069%C2%B6%E1%B9%80%5C.%2B&inputs=&header=&footer=)

Comment: [23 bytes](https://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=Ṫ&code=kA%E2%80%9B%2C%20j%C2%BB%C6%9BL%E1%B8%AD%E2%87%A7%C2%BBS2%E1%BA%87%E2%8C%8A%28n%C2%B6%E1%B9%80%29%5C.&inputs=&header=&footer=)

Comment: [17 bytes](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=2#WyIiLCIiLCJuXFws4bqKODkzMzTCpsOe4bmW4oGL4bmqXFwuKyIsIiIsIiJd)

Comment: [15 bytes](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=2#WyIiLCIiLCJuXFws4bqKNzkzM2bhuofigYvhuapcXC4rIiwiIiwiIl0=). Chunk Wrap doesn't need the last 4 in this case

Answer (score 3):

## Cheddar, 70 bytes

```
->[65@"71,72@"80,"QRS","TUV","WXYZ"].map(@.chars.join(", ")).vfuse+'.'
```

Looks like it's not getting shorter than this. I've made other versions of this which use quite interesting methods but this is shortest

[Try it online!](http://cheddar.tryitonline.net/#code=LT5bNjVAIjcxLDcyQCI4MCwiUVJTIiwiVFVWIiwiV1hZWiJdLm1hcChALmNoYXJzLmpvaW4oIiwgIikpLnZmdXNlKycuJw&input=)

### Explanation

```
->                        // Function with no arguments
  [                       // Array, each item represents a line
   65@"71,                // See below on what @" does
   72@"80,
   "QRS",
   "TUV",
   "WXYZ"
  ].map(                  // On each item...
    @.chars.join(", ")    // Join the characters on ", "
  ).vfuse                 // Vertical fuse or join by newlines
  + '.'                   // The period at the end
```

---

The `@"` operator is used to generate string ranged. It generates a string starting from the left char code to the right char code.

For example, `65` is the char code for `A` and `90` for `Z`. Doing `65 @" 90` would generate A through Z or the alphabet.

Answer (score 3):

## MATL, <s>38</s> 29 bytes

*9 bytes saved thanks to @Luis!*

```
1Y2X{', '&Zc46h1[CEII]I*11hY{
```

[**Try it Online!**](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=MVkyWHsnLCAnJlpjNDZoMVtDRUlJXUkqMTFoWXs&input=)

**Explanation**

```
1Y2     % Push the upper-case alphabet to the stack
X{      % Break the character array into a cell array (similar to a list)
        % where each element is a letter
', '&Zc % Combine back into a string with ', ' between each element
46h     % Append '.' (via ASCII code) to the end of the string
1       % Push the number 1
[CEII]  % Push the array: [7, 9, 3, 3]
I*      % Multiply this array by 3: [21, 27, 9, 9]  
llh     % Append an 11 to this array: [21, 27, 9, 9, 11] 
Y{      % Break our comma-separated list of characters into groups of this size
        % Implicitly display the result
```

Answer (score 3):

### C, <del>112</del> <del>102</del> 81 bytes

Thanks to cleblanc & LevelRiverSt!

```c
i,c;main(){for(c=64;++c<91;)printf("%c%c%c",c,44+c/90*2,c=="‌​GPSVZ"[i]?++i,10:32)‌​;}
```

Comment: Nice solution.  you can save a few bytes as 44 is 1 less than ',' and 46 1 less than '.'

Comment: There's no need to declare int and you can make can d implicit ints as well, this is only 101 bytes `i,c,d;main(){for(c=65;c<91;++c){if(c-"GPSVZ"[i])d=32;else d=10,++i;printf("%c%c%c",c,c-90?44:46,d);}}`

Comment: You can get this approach down to 82 bytes: `i,c;main(){for(c=64;++c<91;)printf("%c%c%c",c,44+c/90*2,c=="GPSVZ"[i]?++i,10:32);}` . Note that you can stick absolutely *anything* between the `?:` of a ternary operator, even several expressions separated by commas (it evaluates to the last one.)

Answer (score 3):

## Japt, 24 bytes

```
;B¬qJ+S r"[HQTW]"@R+XÃ+L
```

[Test it online!](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=master&code=O0KscUorUyByIltIUVRXXSJAUitYwytM&input=)

#### How it works

```
;                        // Reset various variables. B is set to "ABC...XYZ", J is set to ",", and L is set to ".".
 B¬                      // Take the uppercase alphabet and split into chars.
   qJ+S                  // Join with ", ".
        r"[HQTW]"        // Replace each H, Q, T, or W with
                 @R+XÃ   //   a newline plus the character.
                      +L // Append a period to the result.
                         // Implicit: output last expression
```

Answer (score 3):

## Ruby, <s>56</s> 54 bytes

```
$><<(?A..?Y).map{|c|c+('GPSV'[c]?",
":", ")}.join+"Z."
```

The first line ends with a literal newline.

**Edit:** saved two bytes by replacing `'A'..'Y'` with `?A..?Y`.

Answer (score 3):

## Java, <s>116</s> <s>109</s> <s>105</s> 104

```java
String f(){String s="";for(char c=65;c<91;)s=s+c+(c>89?46:',')+("GPSV".indexOf(c++)<0?' ':10);return s;}
```

Ungolfed:

```java
String f() {
  String s = "";
  for (char c = 65; c < 91;) {
    s = s + c
      + (c > 89 ? 46 : ',')
      + ("GPSV".indexOf(c++) < 0 ? ' ' : 10);
  }
  return s;
}
```

Comment: You can golf it by 7 bytes: All three `||` to `|` (-3); changing `c==90` to `c>89` (-1); changing `'.'` to `46` (-1); and changing `'\n'` to `10` (-2).

Comment: @KevinCruijssen thanks, I tried using decimals but it looks like if I replace both character constants in a ternary it changes the expression type to integer, which broke it. Changing one constant worked and squeezed out a few bytes.

Comment: No problem. Don't forget to change the `116` to `<s>116</s> 109 bytes`. ;)

Comment: @KevinCruijssen thanks. If I had enough coffee in me I would have remembered to update it myself.

Comment: 2 more bytes: `"GPSV".contains(""+c)` instead of `c==71|c==80|c==83|c==86`.

Comment: @TNT I was able to do slightly better. I knew that part could be improved, thanks for the push in the right direction.

Comment: You can golf one more byte I now notice. You can remove the `++c` from the for-loop, and put it at the last usage inside the for-body: `.indexOf(c++)`.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen thanks. I always overlook that. I also do a bit of C++ programming and that wanders into UB in C++, but not in Java.

Comment: [84 bytes](https://tio.run/##LY1PS8MwHIbv/RQ/AmWJ2UKHMjuz1ps3TwMPioeYrVtqmoT8KYzRz17j9PTy8D68by9GseoP37ManPUR@swsRaVZl4yMyhp2xwupRQjwKpSBawHg0pdWEkIUMcdo1QGG3OF99MqcPj5B@FMgNxXg5X9n95a9Jfw5LXTQzOOqvY7CQ2gQ4p31WJ4zyWbzwCmVu23FSaCNpGiJKJZlvSnr@7Kuysd1Wz0vYPG0rgj3x5i8gUDRO0N8mvntdX8J8TgwmyJz@TDijgnn9AWbpDUhv9JUTPMP) but [outgolfed anyway](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/231258/16236)

Answer (score 2):

## q, 46 bytes

```
-1@'(", "sv/:0 7 16 19 22_,:'[.Q.A]),'",,,,.";
```

Answer (score 2):

### PowerShell v3+, <s>60</s> <s>78</s> 67 bytes

```
-join(65..90|%{[char]$_+'.,'[$_-le89]+" "+"`n"*($_-in71,80,83,86)})
```

OK. I've actually read, understood, and followed the spec this time. Promise. :D

Takes the array `65..90` and loops over each element `|%{...}`. Each iteration, we're constructing a new string using concatenation, indexing, and multiplication.

First, we take the current number and `char` cast it to make it an ASCII letter. That's concatenated with another char, based on indexing into the string `'.,'` whether we're at `90` or not (i.e., to account for `Z.` while having all the rest be commas). That's string concatenated with `" "` to space-separate the letters, and string multiplication of `` "`n" `` based on Boolean value for whether the current element is `-in` the specified array (i.e., whether we need to concatenate on a newline character). The resulting string is left on the pipeline.

Those strings are encapsulated in parens, and `-join`ed together into a new string, which is then also left on the pipeline and implicit `Write-Output` at the end prints the result. Since we have `` `n `` in the string, it's automatically converted to newlines upon printing.

Requires v3+ for the `-in` operator. Has a trailing space on each line, which is OK per the challenge specs.

#### Example

```
PS C:\Tools\Scripts\golfing> .\now-i-know-my-abc.ps1
A, B, C, D, E, F, G, 
H, I, J, K, L, M, N, O, P, 
Q, R, S, 
T, U, V, 
W, X, Y, Z.
```

Answer (score 2):

## PHP, 62 Bytes

```
<?=preg_filter("# ([HQTW])#","\n$1",join(", ",range(A,Z)));?>.
```

only for comparison 87 Bytes

```
<?="A, B, C, D, E, F, G,\nH, I, J, K, L, M, N, O, P,\nQ, R, S,\nT, U, V,\nW, X, Y, Z.";
```

Comment: You can save a byte by using an actual newline in place of the `\n`.

Comment: As you're allowed trailing spaces on each line you can save a byte by dropping the space from the regex.
Also you can save a byte by using the (deprecated and removed in 7.0) ereg_replace as it lets you skip the delimiters in the regex.

Comment: @user59178 I could save 3 Bytes but i would avoid this. Yes the trailing space is allowed. I could wrote as regex `"# (?=[HQTW])#"` and short the replace to `"\n"` same bytes and makes it clearer. To use a deprecated function can confuse beginners. And the physical break can interpreted wrong on other systems then Unix. You can  post it as your own sugesstion.

Answer (score 2):

### R, 146 bytes

```r
L=LETTERS
f=function(x,y=""){paste(x,collapse=paste0(", ",y))}
cat(f(c(f(L[1:7]),f(L[8:16]),f(L[17:19]),f(L[20:22]),f(L[23:26])),"\n"),".",sep="")
```

**Explanation:**

`LETTERS` is predefined for uppercase letters.
The `f` function is for concatenating vector x on `,` with additional `y` (used for newlines).
The cat is the used as it prints `\n` as newlines. `f` is called on the letters to form rows and then on the rows again to form the whole output.

*Probably golfable - I don't like the multiple calls of f...*

Comment: The raw output is only 77 bytes long. Printing that directly might be shorter...

Comment: @Lynn, I know, but here I see some golfing possibilities.

Answer (score 2):

## Pyth, 25 bytes

```
+Pjmj\ dc*G\,j94092 23)\.
```

A program that prints the result to STDOUT.

[Try it online](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%2BPjmj%5C+dc%2aG%5C%2Cj94092+23%29%5C.&debug=0)

**How it works**

```
+Pjmj\ dc*G\,j94092 23)\.  Program. Input: none
          G                Yield string literal'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
         * \,              Cartesian product of that with ',', yielding a list of
                           characters with appended commas
             j94092 23)    Yield the integer 94092 in base-23, giving [7, 16, 19, 22]
        c                  Split the comma-appended character list at those indices
   mj\                     Join each element of that on spaces
  j                        Join that on newlines
 P                         All but the last element of that, removing trailing ','
+                      \.  Append '.'
                           Implicitly print
```

Answer (score 2):

### [Pip](http://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), 19 bytes

18 bytes of code, +1 for the `-n` flag. Outputs in lowercase.

```
(zJk).'.^@A*"?09B"
```

The `?` represents a non-printing character, ASCII code 21. [Try it online!](http://pip.tryitonline.net/#code=KHpKaykuJy5eQEEqIhUwOUIi&input=&args=LW4)

#### Explanation

```
 z                  Lowercase alphabet
  Jk                Join on ", "
(   ).'.            Append a period
          A*"?09B"  Map ascval() over that string, results in list: [21 48 57 66]
        ^@          Split at those indices
                    Join on newline and print (implicit, -n flag)
```

Answer (score 2):

## CJam, 31 bytes

```
'[,65>", "*7933Ab{3*/(\:+}%N*'.
```

Explanation:

```
'[,65>                             push uppercase alphabet
      ", "*                        ", " between all letters
           7933Ab                  push [7 9 3 3]
                 {3*/(\:+}%        slices of lengths 21, 27, 9, 9
                           N*'.    join slices with newlines, add final "."
```

[Try it online](http://cjam.tryitonline.net/#code=J1ssNjU-IiwgIio3OTMzQWJ7MyovKFw6K30lTionLg&input=)

Answer (score 2):

## Julia, 71 bytes

```
f()=join(join.(['A':'G','H':'P',"QRS","TUV","WXYZ"],[", "]),",\n")*"."
```

Requires 0.5 or better for broadcasting `.()`

Comment: On the one hand, this currently does not have a trailing period, and doesn't it need a `print`/function definition? On the other hand, not saving `join` to a variable saves a byte.

Comment: My bad wrt missing the ".", and thanks for the pointer on `join`. I misscounted. Running the program returns the string.
Isn't a program returning a string a valid output?
(Or is it only functions that are allowed to return things to count as output.
if so `f()=` is shorter thant `print()`)

Comment: Sure, `f()=` or `()->` is fine - I think the idea is that functions are assignable and can be run multiple times, and in contrast this would be a code snippet.

Answer (score 2):

## Cheddar, 57 bytes

```
->(65@"90).sub(/[GPSV]/g,"$0
").sub(/[^Z\n]/g,"$0, ")+"."
```

[Try it online!](http://cheddar.tryitonline.net/#code=LT4oNjVAIjkwKS5zdWIoL1tHUFNWXS9nLCIkMAoiKS5zdWIoL1teWlxuXS9nLCIkMCwgIikrIi4i&input=) Isn't that beautiful? It's a nice rectangle.

Two regex substitutions. `(65@"90)` is the uppercase alphabet, `.sub(/[GPSV]/g,"$0\n")` replaces `GPSV` with itself and `"\n"`, `.sub(/[^Z\n]/g,"$0, ")` replaces all non newline and `Z` characters with itself and `", "`, and `"."` adds a final `.`.

Comment: Nice technique, and nice job outgolfing Downgoat ;)

Answer (score 2):

## TI-Basic, 86 bytes

Cheers to anyone who can compress it further :3

```
Disp "A, B, C, D, E, F, G,","H, I, J, K, L, M, N, O, P,","Q, R, S,","T, U, V,
"W, X, Y, Z.
```

Comment: I think this is optimal, unfortunately.

Answer (score 2):

## [MathGolf](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf), 20 bytes

```
'A[793∙]öæ└╣·\n\\;'.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASoA1f9tYXRoZ29sZv//J0FbNzkz4oiZXcO2w6bilJTilaPCt1xuXFw7Jy7///8)

### Explanation

```
'A                    Push "A"
  [793∙]              Push [7, 9, 3, 3, 3]
        ö             Start foreach-loop over index array using next 7 instructions
         æ            Start for-loop for current item of index array, using next 4 instructions
          └           Duplicate and increment, e.g. "A" -> "A", "B"
           ╣·         Push ", "
             \        Swap top two, keeping the letter on top after inner loop
              n\      Push newline and swap top two, keeping the letter on top
                \;'.  Swap top two, discard top, and push "." (remove trailing comma)
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) [`-R`](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/), 17 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
;LiB¬q,ú2¹óÏk`qw
```

[Test it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LVI&code=O0xpQqxxLPoyufPPa2BxkHc)

```
;LiB¬q,ú2¹óÏk`qw
;L                   :"."
  i                  :Prepend
;  B                 :  Uppercase alphabet
    ¬                :  Split
     q               :  Join with
      ,ú2            :    "," right padded with spaces to length 2
         ¹           :End prepend
          ó          :Partition before characters that return a falsey value (empty string)
           Ï         :When passed through the following function
            k        :  Case insensitively remove
             `qw     :  Characters in the compressed string "qthw"
                     :Implicit output joined with newlines
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Java (JDK)](http://jdk.java.net/), 66 bytes

```java
v->"ABCDEFG\nHIJKLMNOP\nQRS\nTUV\nWXY".replaceAll(".","$0, ")+"Z."
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LY3JTsNAEETv/orWiIMNTot7IFJYwho2Q9jMYXDsaEy7PfL0WIpQvt0MgVOpVE@vat3rUb38Gkxj206gDh29GMLKcyGmZdwdRwVp52CuDcN3BGD9J5kCnGgJ0bdmCU3Y4kw6w6v3D9DdyiVbFGD27zlYBC6FP2YCFRwO/WiipkfHJ6ezs5zPLy6vruc3t3c53z9kOT8@LXJ@fnlV2JWWdFFOiWKFKlU7@ymoZE@9oRrG249s7aRssPWCNuglrlBbS@uYPVGS/EKbaDP8AA)

Answer (score 2):

## C (76 bytes)

```
c;main(){for(c=64;++c<90;)printf("%c,%c",c," \n"[4784256>>c&1]);puts("Z.");}
```

This relies on

1. implicit-`int` declarations (for `c`, `main`, `puts` and `printf` without `#include<stdio.h>`);
2. ASCII;
3. `>>` being modulo the size of an integer in bits, either 32 or 64, so that `X>>'A'` gives "`X` shifted by 1" and `X>>'Z'` gives "`X` shifted by 26".

`4784256` is `2⁷+2¹⁶+2¹⁹+2²²` (or equivalently `1<<7 | 1<<16 | 1<<19 | 1<<22`), because 'G', 'P', 'S', and 'V' are respectively the 7th, 16th, 19th, and 22nd letters of the alphabet.

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, 90 chars

```
A<?for($i=66;$i<91;$i++){echo", ";if(in_array($i,[72,81,84,87]))echo"\n";echo chr($i);}?>.
```

I know it's longer than 77 chars, but this is as short as it gets.

Comment: timmyRS, When I noticed the "." outside your closing tag, I thought  for a split second that you had an error, but I realized you were saving the trouble of concatenating that into your existing string. But, that also made me realize that anything greater than 77 bytes is overkill because you could to the whole thing as plain text and it would work just as well as your ".".

Comment: @TecBrat Well I fixed it now ;P

Answer (score 1):

## Retina, 43 bytes

```
Z
{2`
$`
}T01`L`_L
.
$&, 
[HQTW]
¶$&
, $
.
```

Leading newline is significant. [Try it online!](http://retina.tryitonline.net/#code=CloKezJgCiRgCn1UMDFgTGBfTAouCiQmLCAKW0hRVFddCsK2JCYKLCAkCi4&input=)

This is my first time using Retina, so any golfing tips are appreciated...

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, <s>67</s> <s>65</s> 64 bytes

Not exactly short, but it works.
This assumes that all errors are going to `stderr`.

```
foreach(range(A,Z)as$C)echo$C,",."[$C>Y],"
 "[!strstr(GPSV,$C)];
```

You can try it on `http://ideone.com/VSK8Yu`.

Thanks to [@Jörg Hülsermann](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/59107/j%C3%B6rg-h%C3%BClsermann) for saving 2 bytes!
And thanks to [@Titus](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/55735/titus) for saving me 1 byte!

Comment: `$C>Y` instead of `$C==Z` saves one Byte and 'strstr(GPSV,$C)' instead of `strpos(zGPSV,$C)` should also save one Byte

Comment: @JörgHülsermann That is pure genious! I should have though about that!

Comment: @ETHproductions Duh, stupid me. Thanks, I totally forgot about it.

Comment: Uhm ... don´t you need all doublequotes for `-r`?

Comment: @Titus Why would you? But, if you want, I can use doublequotes. It doesn't change the meaning at all.

Comment: because you need the single quotes to hide the code from the shell.

Comment: @Titus You can always escape them, but I've made the change.

Comment: @Titus What byte?

Comment: You can save one more byte by swapping newline and space and removing one of the exclams. That´ll beat ETHproductions´ JavaScript answer.

Comment: @Titus I tried it, it gives me bizarre outputs in PHP 7.0.5.

Comment: works fine for me in php 5.6.23 and php 7.0.11. Did you forget to swap the characters? Tryp copy & paste `"\n "[!strstr(GPSV,$c)]`

Comment: @Titus http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/8d778160ea897b462d64b332a77a150ff18d33fa gives a different output when compared to http://ideone.com/VSK8Yu which is **SO** weird!

Comment: Unix LF Windows CR LF Apple CR can only works on an unix system `"\n "[!strstr(GPSV,$c)]` should work on every system. By the way the solution you have found Ismael is more genious

Comment: Yep. But that´d cost the byte that the swapping saved. I tend to not use physical linebreaks anymore anyway, because in CLI it has to be escaped, which adds - in my understanding - one byte to the count.

Comment: @JörgHülsermann To be honest, yours is better. Also, all answers assume that you are using *NIX newlines. Using `\n` is 1 more byte than I want. If you **really** need Windows-style or Linux-style, just use `\r\n` or just state that you assume Windows newlines.

Comment: Ismael your way is more interesting that the way I've found. You can take @Titus proposal and forget the output of the sandbox site

Comment: @JörgHülsermann I found your way more interesting. I really didn't remember about using `preg_filter()`. And i will use Titus' suggestion. I didn't use it at first since it was spitting trashy output, but I will use now and give the link to ideone. An answer is valid as long as it is reproducible in, at least, 1 environment.

Comment: It seems so we need judjes which way is more interesting. Normally I would use `preg_replace` (interest approaches zero) and the variation with `preg_filter` saves 1 Byte in some cases. You can be proud to find your way that is more genious

Comment: @JörgHülsermann I think yours is more interesting because of `preg_filter`. In fact, I didn't even knew that that function existed.

Comment: Beauty is in the eye of the beholder. :D

Comment: @Titus Agreed. But what would be trully beautiful would be to reduce `strstr(GPSV,$C)` to a single bitwise operation.

Answer (score 1):

## Forth, 85 bytes

This is a function that prints the string. Checking for when to print a new line is costly. This is still shorter than simply printing the required string, because it has new lines in it. The code does not need to be on this many lines, but there does need to be a line break within the `DO LOOP` somewhere. I don't know why.

```
: f 90 65 DO
I 72 = I 81 = I 84 = I 87 = + + +
if CR then
I emit ." , "
LOOP ." Z." ;
```

[**Try it online**](https://repl.it/Dlka)

The code is case-insensitive.

Answer (score 1):

## Ruby, 57 bytes

```
26.times{|i|$><<(i+65).chr+",."[i/25]+" 
"[2392128>>i&1]}
```

The space at the end of the first line is required: it's a literal [space][newline.]

## C,74 bytes

```
c;main(){for(;++c<27;)printf("%c%c%c",64+c,44+c/26*2,4784256>>c&1?10:32);}
```

Basic bitshift and mask to determine when to print a space and when to print a newline. I noted that with the A and Z removed all groups are a multiple of 3 letters long, but I was unable to make use of this.

Comment: That `4784256>>c&1` is a great idea. But you should probably post the two languages as two separate answers.

Answer (score 1):

### Racket 173 bytes

```
(λ()(let((l(list 7 9 3 3 4))(s 65))(for((i 5))(define e(+ s(list-ref l i)))(for((j(range s e)))
(printf"~a~a "(integer->char j)(if(= j 90)"."",")))(printf"~n")(set! s e))))
```

Ungolfed:

```
(define f
  (λ()
    (let ((l (list 7 9 3 3 4))
          (s 65))
      (for ((i 5))
        (define e (+ s (list-ref l i)))
        (for ((j (range s e)))
          (printf "~a~a " (integer->char j) (if(= j 90) "." ",")))
        (printf "~n")
        (set! s e)
        ))))
```

Testing:

```
(f)
```

Output:

```
A, B, C, D, E, F, G, 
H, I, J, K, L, M, N, O, P, 
Q, R, S, 
T, U, V, 
W, X, Y, Z.
```

Answer (score 1):

## Haskell, 60 bytes

```haskell
putStr$(['A'..'Y']>>= \x->x:", "++['\n'|elem x"GPSV"])++"Z."
```

[Try it on Ideone.](http://ideone.com/Rp9h1M)

```haskell
putStr$(['A'..'Y']>>= \x->x:", "++['\n'|elem x"GPSV"])++"Z."
        ['A'..'Y']                                          --String "ABC...XY"
                      \x->x:", "++['\n'|elem x"GPSV"]       --function to append ", " and a "\n" when needed
       (          >>=                                )      --map function over the string and concat
                                                      ++"Z."--append "Z."
putStr$                                                     --print
```

Answer (score 1):

## Fourier, 56 bytes

```
|~S44a32aS^|f|(iaf~i)10a|L65~i72L81L84L87L90(iaf~i)ia46a
```

Again, uses functions to take out repeated parts of the code.

[**Try it FourIDE!**](https://labs.turbo.run/beta/fourIDE/editor/?code=fH5TNDRhMzJhU158ZnwoaWFmfmkpMTBhfEw2NX5pNzJMODFMODRMODdMOTAoaWFmfmkpaWE0NmE)

Answer (score 1):

### Clojure, 154 bytes

```clj
#(print(loop[a(map char(range 65 91))[c & d][7 9 3 3 4]s""](if c(let[[l r](split-at c a)e(if d\,\.)](recur r d(str s(clojure.string/join", "l)e"\n")))s)))
```

That call to `clojure.string/join` is killer, although this wasn't competitive to begin with. Basically, it cuts the generated alphabet string `a` at the predefined line lengths, then adds each line to the `acc`.

It would have been significantly shorter for me to just "cheat" and print the string (91 bytes):

```clj
(print "A, B, C, D, E, F, G,\nH, I, J, K, L, M, N, O, P,\nQ, R, S,\nT, U, V,\nW, X, Y, Z.")
```

But where's the fun in that?

Ungolfed:

```clj
(defn abcs []
  (print
    (loop [alpha (map char (range 65 91))
           [c & cuts] [7 9 3 3 4]
           acc ""]
      (if c
        (let [[a-line a-rest] (split-at c alpha)
              e (if cuts \, \.)]
          (recur a-rest cuts (str acc (clojure.string/join ", " a-line) e "\n")))
        acc))))
```

Answer (score 1):

## GameMaker Language, 85 bytes

```
b=""for(a=65;a<90;a++){d=chr(a)c=", "if string_pos(d,"GPSV")c=",#"b+=d+c}return b+"Z.
```

**Boring alternate (94 bytes)**

```
return string_replace_all("AaBaCaDaEaFaG,#HaIaJaKaLaMaNaOaP,#QaRaS,#TaUaV,#WaXaYaZ.","a",", ")
```

Pretty straightforward. Note that `#` is newline literal (think `\n` in most languages). Use `\#` for `#`.

Answer (score 1):

## [><>](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), 52 bytes

```
79334"A"\
or:?!~r&>:o1+:}&a" ,.["{=:}?$~o{?;{1-:}?$~
```

[Try it online!](http://fish.tryitonline.net/#code=NzkzMzQiQSJcCm9yOj8hfnImPjpvMSs6fSZhIiAsLlsiez06fT8kfm97Pzt7MS06fT8kfg&input=)

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, <s>61</s> <s>58</s> <s>55</s> 50 bytes

Note: uses Windows 1252 encoding.

```
for($a=A;$a<Z;)echo"$a,",~ßõ[!trim($a++,GPSV)]?>Z.
```

Run like this:

```
php -r 'for($a=A;$a<Z;)echo"$a,",~ßõ[!trim($a++,GPSV)]?>Z.' 2>/dev/null;echo
```

If your terminal is set to UTF-8, this shows that it works:

```
php -r 'for($a=A;$a<Z;)echo"$a,"," \n"[!trim($a++,GPSV)]?>Z.' 2>/dev/null;echo
```

## Explanation

Iterates over the alphabet until `Y` is reached. Prints the letter with a comma, then prints a space, unless the letter is one of `GPSV` (found by `!trim($a,"GPSV")`). After the loop, print `Z.`.

## Tweaks

- Saved 3 bytes by using `strpos` instead of char count
- Saved 3 bytes by using trim instead of strpos
- Saved 5 bytes by using the closing tag to print a literal `Z.` instead of `echo`

Answer (score 1):

**q, 41 bytes**

```
@[", "sv,:'[.Q.A];20 47 56 65;:;"\n"],"."
```

How it works:

```
            .Q.A                          / Built-in alphabet
        ,:'[    ]                         / Flip data (to 1-row matrix)
  ", "sv                                  / Join with ", "
@[               ;20 47 56 65;:;"\n"]     / Replace spaces with newlines at indices
                                     ,"." / Append period
```

Answer (score 1):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 56 bytes

```powershell
('ABCDEFG
HIJKLMNOP
QRS
TUV
WXY'-replace'.','$0, ')+'Z.'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/X0Pd0cnZxdXNncvD08vbx9fPP4ArMCiYKyQ0jCs8IlJdtyi1ICcxOVVdT11HXcVAR0FdU1s9Sk/9/38A)

Comment: [53 bytes?](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/XzcrPzNPQ91RXU9PPVK9RrVaJV5bSUdBSbcotSAnMTlVPdojMCQ8Vl1HnUtFTb1WU1s9Sk/9/38A "PowerShell – Try It Online")

Comment: Thanks. It's cool. A char range allowed in `Powershell 6+` only. I think it would be better if you create a new post with `Powershell 6`.

Comment: Ok, I will. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

## [><>](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), 45 bytes

```
4339"A"7v$oa~<
"&+oo1+$>:1(?^1-$:o:"Z"=2*&" ,
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8sszvj/38TY2FLJUcm8TCU/sc6GS0lNOz/fUFvFzspQwz7OUFfFKt9KKUrJ1khLTUlB5/9/AA)

Answer (score 1):

## PowerShell 6, <s>53</s> <s>52</s> 47 bytes

```
"$('A'..'Y'|%{"$_,"-replace'[HQTW]','
$&'}) Z."
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/X0lFQ91RXU9PPVK9RrVaSSVeR0m3KLUgJzE5VT3aIzAkPFZdR51LRU29VlMhSk/p/38A)

I believe PowerShell 6 is newer than this challenge. Originally posted as a suggestion for @mazzy's solution.

Answer (score 1):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 16 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
é╡₧!D☻àw╟`«▒Σ╪░↓
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=82b59e2144028577c760aeb1e4d8b019&i=&a=1&m=2)

Unpacked, ungolfed, and commented, it looks like this.

```
'.          push "."
VA          push "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
',\         repeat zip alphabet with comma, yielding ["A,", "B,", ...]
J           join with spaces
)           overwrite end of joined string with period (pushed first)
"r!WEF"!    crammed array literal for [20, 47, 56, 65]
A&          assign 10 to these array indices.  10 is the codepoint for newline.
```

[Run this one](https://staxlang.xyz/#c=%27.++++++%09push+%22.%22%0AVA++++++%09push+%22ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ%22%0A%27,%5C+++++%09repeat+zip+alphabet+with+comma,+yielding+[%22A,%22,+%22B,%22,+...]%0AJ+++++++%09join+with+spaces%0A%29+++++++%09overwrite+end+of+joined+string+with+period+%28pushed+first%29%0A%22r%21WEF%22%21%09crammed+array+literal+for+[20,+47,+56,+65]%0AA%26++++++%09assign+10+to+these+array+indices.++10+is+the+codepoint+for+newline.&i=&a=1&m=2)

Answer (score 1):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), <s>30</s> 29 [bytes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9429/43319)<sup>[SBCS](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS)</sup>

Full program.

```apl
↑'AHQTW'(∊⍨⊂⊢)'.',⍨∊', '∘,¨⎕a
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///qKM97f@jtonqjh6BIeHqGo86uh71rnjU1fSoa5Gmup66DojX0aWuo6D@qGOGzqEVj/qmJoJ0/U8DAA)

`⎕a` the uppercase **a**lphabet

`', '∘,¨` prepend `", "` to each letter

`∊` **ϵ**nlist (flatten)

`'.',⍨` append a period

`'AHQTW'(`…`)` apply the following tacit function with the string as left argument:

`⊢` the right argument (`", A, B…"`)

`⊂` partitioned so a new partition begins at each True in

`∊⍨` the Boolean mask indicating argument elements that are members of the left argument

`↑` mix the list of strings into a character matrix

[solved together with Adam](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/49340897#49340897)

Answer (score 1):

## [ReRegex](https://github.com/TehFlaminTaco/ReRegex), 47 bytes

```
-/,\n/\w\B/$0, /ABCDEFG-HIJKLMNOP-QRS-TUV-WXYZ.
```

### Ungolfed

```
-/,\n/                             # Replace all dashes with a comma and newline
\w\B/$0, /                         # Replace all letters preceeding a letter with itself and a comma space.
ABCDEFG-HIJKLMNOP-QRS-TUV-WXYZ.    # The default code.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otSk1Prfj/X1dfJyZPP6Y8xklfxUBHQd/RydnF1c1d18PTy9vH188/QDcwKFg3JDRMNzwiMkrv/38A)

Answer (score 1):

## [sed](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/), 54 bytes

No [further tricks](https://tio.run/##K05N0U3PK/3/v1hfRd/RydnF1c1dn8udq1hf38PTy9vH188/AMoPDAqGskJCw6Cs8IjIKD19ICvaUTcyVl9NR0E//f9/AA) take us down, I'm afraid:

```
s/^/ABCDEFG\
HIJKLMNOP\
QRS\
TUV\
WXYZ./
s/[A-Y]/&, /g
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K05N0U3PK/3/v1g/Tt/RydnF1c09hsvD08vbx9fPPyCGKzAoOIYrJDQshis8IjJKT5@rWD/aUTcyVl9NR0E//f9/AA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Ly](https://github.com/LyricLy/Ly), 29 bytes

```
'A043397[[r:o`r' ',oo,]p9`o];
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y6n8/1/d0cDE2NjSPDq6yCo/oUhdQV0nP18ntsAyIT/W@v9/AA)

This code pushes the number of letters to print on each line onto the stack. It also keeps the current character on the end of the stack, iterating it each time it prints.  The code loops until the "number of letters to print on the next line" is zero.

```
'A                            - push "A" on the stack
  0                           - add 0 divider to stop loop
   43397                      - push number of chars per line
        [                  ]  - loop while number of chars>0
         [           ,]       - loop for one line of chars
          r                   - reverse stack
           :                  - duplicate current char
            o                 - print
             `                - increment to next char
              r               - reverse stack again
               ' ',oo         - push/print " ,"
                       p      - delete iterator var
                        9`o   - push/print LF
                            ; - exit to abandon junk on stack
```

Answer (score 0):

## [///](//esolangs.org/wiki////), 62 bytes

```
/c/, /AcBcCcDcEcFcG,
HcIcJcKcLcMcNcOcP,
QcRcS,
TcUcV,
WcXcYcZ.
```

[Try it online!](//slashes.tryitonline.net#code=L2MvLCAvQWNCY0NjRGNFY0ZjRywKSGNJY0pjS2NMY01jTmNPY1AsClFjUmNTLApUY1VjViwKV2NYY1ljWi4)

Not much to golf here, but I reduced it from 77 bytes to 62 just by replacing `,`  with `c`.

Comment: What would `//, /ABCDE...` do?

Comment: @ETHproductions It might crash your computer. I put a `c` for `c`omma.

Comment: @ETHproductions Substitutions are repeated until the search string is no longer found. So `//.../` will always result in an infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

### [ListSharp](https://github.com/timopomer/ListSharp), 88 bytes

```
SHOW="A, B, C, D, E, F, G,\nH, I, J, K, L, M, N, O, P,\nQ, R, S,\nT, U, V,\nW, X, Y, Z."
```

Comment: Couldn't you put the `\n` in the string? It looks like that would be shorter.

Comment: @Timtech oh dang, I thought im smart but im not

Comment: It's ok. Just something like `SHOW="A, B, C, D, E, F, G,\nH, I, J, K, L, M, N, O, P,\nQ, R, S,\nT, U, V,\nW, X, Y, Z."` is 88 bytes instead of 113.

Answer (score 0):

## [Julia 1.0](http://julialang.org/), 53 bytes

```julia
_->replace(join('A':'Z',", "),r"(?=[HQTW])"=>"
")*'.'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0rPifZvs/XteuKLUgJzE5VSMrPzNPQ91R3Uo9Sl1HSUdBSVOnSEnD3jbaIzAkPFZTydZOiUtJU0tdT/1/QVFmXolGmkZefklGZl66puZ/AA)