# Print the Christmas alphabet

Tags: code-golf, kolmogorov-complexity

Write a program to print or return one of these strings verbatim:

```
abcdefghijkmnopqrstuvwxyz

ABCDEFGHIJKMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
```

Notice that there is [no L](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_First_Noel).

Comment: Probably worth saying "Note that there's No**el** in there!" to avoid any confusion.

Comment: Does it have to be printed or can it be returned from a function?

Comment: @Yousername returning it is fine.

Comment: Could be useful, or not: [65-75, 77-90 on oeis](https://oeis.org/search?q=65%2C66%2C67%2C68%2C69%2C70%2C71%2C72%2C73%2C74%2C75%2C+++77%2C78%2C79%2C80%2C81%2C82%2C83%2C84%2C85%2C86%2C87%2C88%2C89%2C90&language=english&go=Search)

Comment: Or, [in song form](https://youtu.be/_52zdiltkRM?&t=43) by Alex Horne and the Horne Section.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 3 bytes

```
⁻βl
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvRMM3M6@0WCNJR0EpR0lT0/r///@6ZTkA) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation: `β` is a Charcoal variable predefined to the lowercase alphabet.

```
⁻αL
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvRMM3M6@0WCNRR0HJR0lT0/r///@6ZTkA) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation: `α` is a Charcoal variable predefined to the uppercase alphabet.

Answer (score 12):

## [brainfuck](https://github.com/TryItOnline/brainfuck), 49 bytes

```
+++++++++++++[->+>+++++>+<<<]>--[->.+<]>>+[-<+.>]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMxLK03O/v9fGxlE69pp24FZdto2Njaxdrq6QCE9bSDLDihpo61nF/v/PwA)

Starting with a cell containing `13` we set up 3 cells containing `13,65,13`. The 65 is the ASCII code of the letter to be printed and the other cells are down-counters (which are adjusted to 11 and 14 before use.) A nice feature is that the loop for printing the first 11 letters increments the ASCII code after printing and the loop printing the last 14 letters increments the ASCII code before printing, thereby skipping L naturally.

Answer (score 10):

## [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/) / MATLAB, <s>21</s> 18 bytes

Anonymous function that takes no inputs and outputs the string with uppercase letters.

```matlab
@()['A':'K' 77:90]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/Z9mq6en999BQzNa3VHdSt1bXcHc3MrSIPZ/SmZxgUaahqbmfwA)

#### How it works

The code concatenates the two ranges of letters: before and after the 'L'. The second range is defined numerically to save two bytes. This can be done because concatenating chars and numbers implicitly converts each number to the char with the corresponding codepoint.

Answer (score 8):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 22 bytes

```r
!Map(cat,letters[-12])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/X9E3sUAjObFEJye1pCS1qDha19AoVvP/fwA)

Exits with an error; credit to [ovs](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/64121/ovs).

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 23 bytes

```r
x=Map(cat,letters[-12])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/v8LWN7FAIzmxRCcntaQktag4WtfQKFbz/38A)

Also credit to ovs.

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 24 bytes

```r
cat(letters[-12],sep="")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/PzmxRCMntaQktag4WtfQKFanOLXAVklJ8/9/AA)

Comment: `x=Map(cat,letters[-12])` saves one I think. Could also think about exiting with error with `!Map...`

Comment: @ovs thanks, both great improvements!

Answer (score 7):

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/), 23 bytes, original answer

```bash
printf %s {a..k} {m..z}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/v6AoM68kTUG1WKE6UU8vu1ahOldPr6r2/38A)

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/), 21 bytes, thanks to Nahuel Fouilleul

```bash
echo {a..z}|tr -d \ l
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/PzU5I1@hOlFPr6q2pqRIQTdFIUYh5/9/AA)

Comment: -2bytes [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/PzU5I1@hOlFPr6q2pqRIQTdFIUYh5/9/AA "Bash – Try It Online")

Comment: @NahuelFouilleul Nice one, added as separate entry.

Answer (score 7):

## [Python](https://www.python.org), 39 bytes

```python
print(25*"%c"%(*{*range(65,91)}-{76},))
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vwYKlpSVpuhY31QuKMvNKNIxMtZRUk5VUNbSqtYoS89JTNcxMdSwNNWt1q83NanU0NSHKobpgugE)

Only 5 bytes longer than hardcoding the entire thing ...

#### How?

Unlike dictionaries, sets are in general not guaranteed to preserve insertion order, so why does this work?

C-Python implementation detail: (small) integers are their own hash values.

Answer (score 6):

## Various Languages, 25 bytes

```
abcdefghijkmnopqrstuvwxyz
```

or

```
ABCDEFGHIJKMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
```

In many languages, the shortest solution is also the least interesting.

Works in: [///](https://esolangs.org/wiki////), [ARBLE](https://github.com/TehFlaminTaco/ARBLE), [PHP](https://php.net/), [ReRegex](https://github.com/TehFlaminTaco/ReRegex), ...

Answer (score 6):

## [PowerShell Core](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 25 bytes

```powershell
-join$('a'..'k';'m'..'z')
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/XzcrPzNPRUM9UV1PTz1b3Vo9F8SoUtf8/x8A)

I think solving that with 25 bytes has a certain *je ne sais quoi*.
Only works in PowerShell Core, Windows PowerShell can't enumerate characters.

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), all flavors, 27 bytes

```powershell
'abcdefghijkmnopqrstuvwxyz'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/Xz0xKTklNS09IzMrOzcvv6CwqLiktKy8orJK/f9/AA)

The boring/trivial solution with 27, which would end up as National Fruitcake Day. Somewhat related to CodeGolf, as golfed code and fruitcake have a similar density.

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), all flavors, 31 bytes

```powershell
-join([char[]]$(65..75;77..90))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/XzcrPzNPIzo5I7EoOjZWRcPMVE/P3NTa3FxPz9JAU/P/fwA)

So here's New Year's Eve.
Which is what we also get from the trivial solution in Batch:

## Windows Batch, 31 bytes

```powershell
@echo abcdefghijkmnopqrstuvwxyz
```

Comment: You can even go down to [21 bytes](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/XzcrPzNPQz1RXU9PvUpdNy9VPUdd8/9/AA "Joyeux Noël!") :)
And 26 for the all flavours version: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/XzcrPzMvOjkjsSg6NlbDzFRPz9JANy/V3Ezz/38A "Noyeux Joël!")

Answer (score 6):

## [Vyxal 3](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal/tree/version-3),, 4 bytes

```
n'l-
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.github.io/latest.html#WyIiLCIiLCJuJ2wtIiwiIiwiIiwiMy4wLjAiXQ==)

First Vyxal answer, so I’m sure there may be a more concise way, but I like that it almost reads ‘no el’!

Comment: What’s nice with this one is that it almost reads as "noel"!

Answer (score 6):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language), 14 bytes

```
26*#
Y`#`l
l
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxLNPz/n8vITEuZKzJBOSGHK4fr/38A) Outputs in lowercase but if the program is uppercased then it will output in uppercase instead. Explanation:

```
26*#
```

Insert 26 `#`s. (I can't use the default `_` because that's a special transliteration character.)

```
Y`#`l
```

Translate each `#` in turn into the next character of the alphabet. (It's possible to skip the `l` here but it's longer overall.)

```
l
```

Remove the `l`.

The best I could do in [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d) without resorting to 26-byte hard-coding was 27 bytes, but with some inspiration from @FryAmTheEggman I got it down to <s>16</s> 15 bytes:

```
T`l`_l
}`$
z
l
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/P8/JCEnIT6HqzZBhauKK4fr/38A) Outputs in lowercase but if the program is uppercased then it will output in uppercase instead. Explanation:

```
T`l`_l
```

Move all of the letters so far one step backwards in the alphabet, but delete any `a`.

```
$
z
```

Append a `z` to the current string.

```
}`
```

Repeat the above until the transformation becomes idempotent. This happens when the string is the entire alphabet; the `a` is deleted, the `b-z` get transliterated into `a-y`, and another `z` is appended.

```
l
```

Remove the `l`.

Comment: I was fiddling in Retina 1 but didn't think of manually inserting the correct number of things. Luckily, [my idea didn't use any new features](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/P@/OiQhPichh8slQY9LMyGOK5Erh@v/fwA).

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman That's a great idea... but I still golfed some more bytes off!

Comment: ... and also a lot of bytes off of two of my other Retina 0.8.2 answers...

Comment: Nice! Using the transliterate to also remove the byte and close the loop makes it a very clean looking solution.

Answer (score 6):

## x86-64 machine code, <del>17</del> 15 bytes

```
B0 E6 04 5B AA 2C 4B 3C 01 14 F1 75 F5 AA C3
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TVFNU8IwED0nv2Ktw5AIZQCVA4gXj44XT47AIU3SNk6aME2LrQx/3brgIF52533s251ZGWdSdp0IBTB4jRgdZdYnwkJK0zkp/A6EHUI8ndFyToRSJ9h/7w8mlITKhwRbnfyyz31KZLE9AZSFkmc@xglKPtwXlH9jpa4oj4Av6M4bBSmTuShvICBBr42TtlYaHkKljB/lj5QaV0EhjGOc7nEPmqHUobbV6n4y3SwoSdkvxgCyLdGesqgXoiFc6Iuwdi9C5sZpkF7peXRUjxsaWMJ4CC1C5WF/tkNvPH3DqHbJWO2CyZxWcDqYp3zVDAYbvjjAZ26sBtbCFYY0T7f/LwHWM5C0lQ587TCpQfHQdd8ytSILXVzM7rDgH5bo1/YH)

Following the standard calling convention for Unix-like systems (from the System V AMD64 ABI), this takes in RDI a memory address at which to place the result, as a null-terminated byte string.

In assembly:

```
f:  mov al, -26     # Set AL to -26.
r:  add al, 'Z'+1   # Add this value to AL to produce a letter.
    stosb           # Write AL to the output string, advancing the pointer.
    sub al, 'K'     # Subtract 'K' from AL.
    cmp al, 1       # Set flags from calculating AL - 1. CF is 1 iff AL is 0.
    adc al, 'K'-'Z' # Add (this value + CF) to AL. The net change is +1 or +2.
    jnz r           # If the result is nonzero, repeat the loop.
    stosb           # Write AL (0) to the output string, advancing the pointer.
    ret             # Return.
```

Answer (score 6):

## [CP-1610](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Instrument_CP1600) machine code, 14 DECLEs<sup>1</sup> = 17.5 bytes

*<sub>1. CP-1610 instructions are encoded with 10-bit values (0x000 to 0x3FF), known as DECLEs. Although the Intellivision is also able to work on 16-bit data, programs were really stored in 10-bit ROM back then.</sub>*

A routine that writes the Christmas alphabet at **R4**.

The method used here would be more relevant if there were several letters to skip. With just one letter, using `SLLC` / `ADCR` only saves a few CPU cycles compared to `CMPI` / `BEQ`.

```
                            ROMW  10          ; use 10-bit ROM
                            ORG   $4800       ; map our code at $4800
                      
4800  02BC 0200             MVII  #$200,  R4  ; R4 = BACKTAB pointer
4802  0004 0148 000D        CALL  alpha       ; invoke our routine
                      
4805  02BD 0030             MVII  #$30,   R5  ; R5 = pointer into STIC registers
4807  01C0                  CLRR  R0
4808  0268                  MVO@  R0,     R5  ; no horizontal delay
4809  0268                  MVO@  R0,     R5  ; no vertical delay
480A  0268                  MVO@  R0,     R5  ; no border extension
480B  0002                  EIS               ; enable interrupts
                      
480C  0017                  DECR  R7          ; loop forever
                      
                            ;; our routine
                      alpha PROC
                      
480D  02B8 010F             MVII  #$010F, R0  ; R0 = letter code, initialized to 'A'
480F  02B9 0010             MVII  #$0010, R1  ; R1 = mask used to skip 'L'
                      
4811  0059            @loop SLLC  R1          ; left-shift the mask into the carry
4812  002F                  ADCR  R7          ; add the carry to the program counter
                                              ; (i.e. skip MVO@ if the carry is set)
4813  0260                  MVO@  R0,     R4  ; write the letter
4814  02F8 0008             ADDI  #8,     R0  ; update R0 to the next letter
4816  0378 01D7             CMPI  #$01D7, R0  ; compare with 'Z'
4818  0226 0008             BLE   @loop       ; loop if less than or equal
                      
481A  00AF                  MOVR  R5,     R7  ; return
                      
                            ENDP
```

### Output

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Congratulations on your 200th k-c post and therefore gold k-c tag badge! (I'm guessing that this one was your 200th, given your badge award date...)

Comment: @Neil It probably was this one indeed. Thank you! And congrats on your 402nd k-c post. ;-)

Comment: Shame I don't qualify for a second gold k-c tag badge ;-)

Answer (score 5):

## [RProgN 2](https://github.com/TehFlaminTaco/RProgN-2), 4 bytes

```
a`l-
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Kyooyk/P0zX6/z8xIUf3/38A)

Or for upper-case

```
A`L-
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Kyooyk/P0zX6/98xwUf3/38A)

Just removes literal `L` from the alphabet builtin.

Answer (score 5):

## [V (vim)](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/V), 14 bytes

```
:h<_
jjYZZPtmx
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/v/3yrDJp4rKysyKiqgJLfi/38A)

[Yet another](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/94983/now-i-know-my-abcs-wont-you-come-and-golf-with-me/94989#94989) post uses [the trick](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/86986/print-a-tabula-recta/87010#87010) found by [Lynn](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/3852/lynn).

Answer (score 5):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 71 bytes

```python
import string as s
print(s.ascii_lowercase[:11]+s.ascii_lowercase[12:])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/PzO3IL@oRKG4pCgzL10hsVihmKsAyCzRKNZLLE7OzIzPyS9PLUpOLE6NtjI0jNXGFDY0sorV/P8fAA)

Comment: 60: `from string import ascii_lowercase as s;print(s[:11]+s[12:])`; 58: `from string import*;s=ascii_lowercase;print(s[:11]+s[12:])`

Comment: The [boring loop is 54 bytes](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/Py2/SCFTITNPoSgxLz1Vw8xUx9JQ04pLITNNIVPR1tzMSqGgKDOvRCM5o0gjU1MnNS/FVl1d8/9/AA "Python 3 – Try It Online"), the [most boring solution only 34 bytes](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/v6AoM69EQ93RydnF1c3dw9PL29fPPyAwKDgkNCw8IjJKXfP/fwA "Python 3 – Try It Online")

Comment: 56: `from string import*;a=printable;print(a[10:21]+a[22:36])`

Comment: Trying to be smart, but sadly 75 bytes: `from math import*;print(''.join(chr(n+isqrt(3*n//2))for n in range(56,81)))`

Comment: @Stef followed your way, and in fact got to 65;see my answer

Comment: @UndoneStudios I cannot find your answer! Where is it?

Comment: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/267148/110681

Answer (score 5):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 13 bytes

```perl
say A..K,M..Z
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/784sVLBUU/PW8dXTy/q//9/@QUlmfl5xf91fU31DAwB)

Answer (score 5):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <sup><strike>51</strike></sup> 50 bytes

```python
print(''.join(chr(i+65)for i in range(26)if i-11))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/v6AoM69EQ11dLys/M08jOaNII1PbzFQzLb9IIVMhM0@hKDEvPVXDyEwzM00hU9fQUFPz/38A)

Simple iteration combining `range` and `chr`.

-1 byte thank to [@UndoneStudios](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/110681)'s amazing hint of using `str.join`

---

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 54 bytes

```python
a=*range(65,91),
print(*map(chr,a[:11]+a[12:]),sep='')
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/P9FWqygxLz1Vw8xUx9JQU4eroCgzr0RDKzexQCM5o0gnMdrK0DBWOzHa0MgqVlOnOLXAVl1d8/9/AA)

Using tuple destructuring.

Comment: -1 byte? `print(''.join(chr(i+65)for i in range(26)if i-11))`

Comment: @UndoneStudios How could I have not thought of that? Thank you so much!

Answer (score 4):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 19 bytes

```ruby
([*?a..?z]-[?l])*''
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72kqDSpcsESFTsbm6WlJWm6Fps1orXsE_X07KtidaPtc2I1tdTVITILoBSUBgA)

Since the task allows simply returning the string instead of printing, I believe it should be acceptable as this snippet. If not, it's +4 for `$><<` in front.

Comment: I think it would be acceptable to make this a function that returns a list of characters, so this works for 18 bytes: [`->{[*?a..?z]-[?l]}`](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72kqDSpcsFSFTsbG42lpSVpuhabdO2qo7XsE_X07KtidaPtc2JrIRIrNfWSE3NytNTVIfwFCyA0AA)

Answer (score 4):

## [morsecco](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/26119/72726): 112 bytes

Yes, that's 4.5 times the size of the pure input, but don't forget that we have only three symbols, resulting in a factor ~5, compared to the full character set.

The whole christmas alphabet in morse code already takes 102 characters; with the overhead of conversion and printing it would be 124 bytes, so this loop solution is shorter *(not counting the christmas tree formatting, which starts beautifully with `E`ntering 65, but doesn't really work out well, because whitespaces are sometimes meaningful in Morsecco)*:

```
   .
-.....-
 -- -
  - -
 -.- -
  . -   
  .--     
. .-..-.--
   .-    
--.. --.-
 . .----   
.- --.. --.
 . -.--.-- 
.- --. --.-   
. -..--.- --.
```

- The first line initializes the stack with 65 (`A`)
- Line 2 sets a jump `M`ark to start a loop, `K`onvert the number to `T`ext and `W`rite it to stdout.
- Now comes the golfing trick: line 3 `A`dds –75 (`K`) and skips after `--.-` is zero (so the last line handles the `L` skipping by `E`ntering 77)
- The 4th line subtracts another 15 to test for the `Z` and skips after the `--.` that closes the loop for the other characters
- The 5th line `A`dds 91 (–75 + –15 + 91 = 1, so the value is incremented) and `G`oes to the mark that was set. This saves three bytes compared to saving a copy of the value, dropping the modified version and adding 1 to the copy.

**Cheating version: 47 bytes**

Yes, morsecco ignores all characters except for dot, dash and space, but to cheat, you can `R`ead the source code from the empty address, `C`ut it after the `Z` and `O`utput. Yes, such tricks are probably legal when golfing, but boring:

```
ABCDEFGHIJKMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ.   .-. -.-. --..- ---
```

Answer (score 4):

## XPath 2: <s>42</s> <s>41</s> 27 bytes

First attempt: 42 bytes

```
codepoints-to-string(remove(97 to 122,12))
```

Explanation:

- `97 to 122` returns the sequence 97, 98, 99, ... 122
- `remove( ..., 12)` removes the 12th item
- `codepoints-to-string()` converts the numbers to a string

The result of the evaluation is the christmas string. [Try it online](http://xpather.com/i1C7g8C1).

---

Second attempt 41 bytes, thanks to @Philippos

```
codepoints-to-string(remove(65 to 90,12))
```

(upper case letters)

---

Third attempt (27 bytes), the "trivial" (but so far the shortest) solution (@jonathan-allan)

```
"abcdefghijkmnopqrstuvwxyz"
```

is a equally valid XPath expression.

Comment: Very nice, thank you for your contribution! You could even save one byte printing the uppercase christmas alphabet: `codepoints-to-string(remove(65 to 90,12))`

Comment: Thank you for both parts of your comment!

Comment: `"abcdefghijkmnopqrstuvwxyz"` saves bytes if that is truly a full-program or function (I do not know XPath, but [it works in the linked _interpreter(?)_](http://xpather.com/qnLFI4Rp)).

Comment: This is a perfectly valid XPath expression, so this is the shortest.

Answer (score 4):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 23 bytes

```
filter(/='L')['A'..'Z']
```

### Explanation

`['A'..'Z']` represents the entire uppercase alphabet, `(/='L')` is a shorthand for the lambda `\x -> x /= 'L'`. When both are passed to `filter`, this keeps all letters from the alphabet that are not `L`.

Alternatively, this can also be done with an extra byte using [list comprehensions](https://wiki.haskell.org/List_comprehension):

```
[x|x<-['A'..'Z'],x/='L']
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf, and nice answer!

Comment: Nice answer! I'm a bit sad that `['A'..'K']++['M'..'Z']` is shorter by a byte :)

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <strike>50</strike> 49 bytes

```
print(''.join(chr(x+x//76)for x in range(65,90)))
```

You could save two bytes by using Python 2, but nobody uses that anymore:

## Python 2, 47 bytes

```
print ''.join(chr(x+x/76)for x in range(65,90))
```

Comment: You don't need the space before `for`.

Comment: @Neil thanks for the hint!

Comment: You can save another byte from the Python 2 version: the space after `print` isn't needed.

Answer (score 3):

## Google Sheets, 45 bytes

`=sort(replace(join(,char(row(65:90))),12,1,))`

...or **47 bytes**:

`=join(,filter(char(row(65:90)),row(65:90)<>76))`

These formulas are longer than their output.

Comment: Wouldn't it be shorter just to write it literally as `abcdefghijkmnopqrstuvwxyz`..?

Comment: Yes. Kinda defeats the purpose though. Spreadsheet formula languages are not optimal in many code-golf questions. The patterns therein may however be of use in other contexts.

Answer (score 3):

## [Uiua](https://uiua.org), 11 [bytes](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/265917/97916)

```
▽≠@l.+@a⇡26
```

[Try it!](https://uiua.org/pad?src=0_3_1__ZiDihpAg4pa94omgQGwuK0Bh4oehMjYKCmYK)

```
▽≠@l.+@a⇡26
        ⇡26  # range from 0 to 25
     +@a     # add letter a
    .        # duplicate
 ≠@l         # where is it not equal to l?
▽            # keep
```

Comment: Same length alternative: `+@a+>10.⇡25`

Answer (score 3):

## [APL (dzaima/APL)](https://github.com/dzaima/APL), 6 bytes

```apl
⎕A~'L'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pSszMTfz/qHfeo7YJGv8f9U11rFP3Uf@v@R8A)

Answer (score 3):

## [sclin](https://github.com/molarmanful/sclin), 9 bytes

```
$abc"l"--
```

[Try it on scline!](https://scline.fly.dev/##H4sIAOYYYGUCA1NJTEpWylHS1QUA1.fRIwkAAAA#)

Very straightforward.

Answer (score 3):

## [Scala](http://www.scala-lang.org/), <del>48</del> 30 bytes

Saved 18 bytes thanks to @corvus_192

---

Golfed version. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY2xCsIwFEX3fMWjS1qoQ9eUDv0AcRAXxeEZ2xhN0pA8xSL9dWOgOB0u515ulGgwTZf7IAm2qB18GMB1GMHmUGJQUUAfAs6nPQXt1LkScHCaoMtN9sIAdl6NgJVd4j2niR@5R5K3smnqoqibyj5Wn1rmM8m48j@tWpZfF7akrxwNqpg2Bp16ohqEnyKN@r3z8Qc)

```scala
'A'to'Z'patch(11,"",1)mkString
```

Comment: `println("abcdefghijkmnopqrstuvwxyz")` saves 12 bytes though.

Comment: 30 bytes: `'A'to'Z'patch(11,"",1)mkString` (requires `-language:postfixOps`)

Answer (score 2):

## [*Acc!!*](https://github.com/dloscutoff/Esolangs/tree/master/Acc!!), 41 bytes

```python
Count i while 25-i {
Write (65+i)*77/76
}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0xOTkr6/985vzSvRCFToTwjMydVwchUN1Ohmiu8KLMkVUHDzFQ7U1PL3Fzf3Iyr9v9/AA)

#### Explanation

Loop `i` from 0 to 24. Add 65 to convert to uppercase codepoints A through Y; then scale by a linear factor to skip over code point 76 (L). (Division in *Acc!!* is integer division, but the floating-point version would be \$ 65.86, 66.87, \cdots, 74.97, 75.99, 77.00, 78.01, \cdots, 90.17 \$)

Answer (score 2):

## [C (GCC)](https://gcc.gnu.org), <s>48</s> <s>46</s> 42 bytes w/ help from @Neil and @ceilingcat

```c
main(x){for(;x++<27;)x-13&&putchar(x+63);}
```

[Attempt this online](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m700OT49OXnBgqWlJWm6Fje1chMz8zQqNKvT8os0rCu0tW2MzK01K3QNjdXUCkpLkjMSizQqtM2MNa1rITqgGmEGAAA)

Comment: `x-27&&(x-12&&putchar(x+64))+main(x+1);` seems to work.

Comment: Or perhaps `x-26&&putchar(x+64+(x>11))+main(x+1);`?

Comment: Yep, that makes better sense :P. Added.

Comment: `c;f(){for(c=64;++c<91;)c-76&&putchar(c);}` is 41 bytes, but `f(){puts("abcdefghijkmnopqrstuvwxyz");}` is 39

Answer (score 2):

## [Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org), <sup><strike>40</strike></sup> 35 bytes

```
{(('a'..'z')-'l').joinToString("")}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JcuxCYAwEEbh3il@bO6uSAYQdAldIE0kGi8i0UJx9hiw/OC9NeUYtPhTsbmgLHgaAJeL8B0qzYAxH0Fn9CgPMzmylm4SQ5HELinolP6C21beUm/slTkqexZp3vIB)

## [Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org), <sup><strike>40</strike></sup> <sup><strike>35</strike></sup> 31 bytes

```
{(('a'..'z')-'l').map(::print)}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcuxDYAgEAXQnil@d3cFDECiWzgADQkRTmLQQsLsSPmKd14tJ53xUZSQlAXdAHhDRvRYtDsOTQ0bZmemQM7RR2Ipk7gSKntf76RNxlwPkcWM@QM)

Lambdas `() -> String` and `() -> Unit`, respectively, that uses [`minus`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/minus.html) applied to a CharRange.

-5 bytes thank to [@corvus_192](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/46901)'s wonderful reminder that `minus` can be replaced by `-`

-4 bytes on `() -> Unit` by replacing the `forEach` with a `map`.

Comment: why not `{(('a'..'z')-'l').joinToString("")}`

Comment: @corvus_192 I've completely forgot that `minus` can be overloaded as `-`. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

## [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/), 27 characters

```
[range(65;91)]-[76]|implode
```

Sample run:

```
bash-5.2$ jq -nr '[range(65;91)]-[76]|implode'
ABCDEFGHIJKMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyr8/z@6KDEvPVXDzNTa0lAzVjfa3Cy2JjO3ICc/JfX//3/5BSWZ@XnF/3V180pzcnQz8wpKS4CcosRy3fzSEiAHAA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 4 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
;BkÊ
```

[Test it here](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=O0Jryg)

Answer (score 2):

## [GolfScript](http://www.golfscript.com/golfscript/), 10 bytes

```
91,65>'L'-
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8/PSStOLsosKPn/39JQx8zUTt1HXff/fwA)

## [GolfScript](http://www.golfscript.com/golfscript/), 11 bytes

```
'alm{'{,^}/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8/PSStOLsosKPn/Xz0xJ7davVonrlb//38A)

Comment: Slightly different 10: [`91,65>76-+`](https://tio.run/##S8/PSStOLsosKPn/39JQx8zUztxMV/v/fwA "GolfScript – Try It Online")

Answer (score 2):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), <s>6</s> 5 bytes

*-1 byte thanks to [@DLosc](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/16766/dlosc)*

```
zRM'l
```

<s>Yea I think that's about as short as it can get, unless someone has some genius strategy.</s>

Turns out I'm not genius enough :P

[Try It Online!](https://dso.surge.sh/#@WyJwaXAiLCIiLCJ6Uk0nbCIsIiIsIiIsIiJd)

Comment: Not a genius strategy, but... [5 bytes](https://dso.surge.sh/#@WyJwaXAiLCIiLCJ6Uk0nbCIsIiIsIiIsIiJd) ;P

Comment: @DLosc I didn't realize that was a thing. Genius :P

Answer (score 2):

## [Knight](https://github.com/knight-lang/knight-lang) (v2), 27 bytes

```
;=a 64W>91=a+1a|?76aO+Aa'\'
```

[Try it online!](https://knight-lang.netlify.app/#WyI7PWEgNjRXPjkxPWErMWF8Pzc2YU8rQWEnXFwnIiwiIiwiMi4wIl0=)

Well, at least it's shorter than this (28 bytes):

```
O"ABCDEFGHIJKMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
```

Answer (score 2):

## Python, 65 bytes:

Uses the formula given by Stef in the comments, so I guess this could probably stay up for not being boring...

```py
lambda:''.join(chr(int(i+((1.5*i)**.5)//1))for i in range(56,81))
```

Answer (score 2):

## [YASEPL](https://github.com/madeforlosers/yasepl-esolang), 26 bytes

algorithmic way of doing it

```
=a$97`1}3,108,2›`2+}2,123
```

## [YASEPL](https://github.com/madeforlosers/yasepl-esolang), 28 bytes

lazy way of doing it

```
>"abcdefghijkmnopqrstuvwxyz"
```

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>5</s> 4 bytes

-1 thanks to noodle man

```
A'lм
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/fUSlH6cKe//8B)

```
A'lм
A       The lowercase alphabet
 'lм    Minus the 'l'
```

Comment: `"l"` can be `'l`

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 9 bytes

```
+<G11>G12
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/X9vG3dDQzt3Q6P9/AA)

##### Explanation

**G** - `Pyth`'s pre-initialised variable to the lowercase letters in the alphabet.

**<** - used to slice the string till 11.

**>** - used to slice the string from 12, thereby leaving the letter `l`.

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 4 bytes | Thanks to [@FryAmTheEggman](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/31625/fryamtheeggman)

```
-G"l
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/X9ddKef/fwA)

Comment: Nice! You can save quite a bit by using `-`, which is overloaded in Pyth to work on strings in a manner similar to how it works on sets.

Answer (score 1):

## Commodore BASIC - 28 characters

Enter this in direct mode, the `?` denotes a `PRINT` command:

```
?"ABCDEFGHIJKMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
```

Note that in Commodore BASIC, you do not necessarily require a closing quotation mark when printing a string literal.

Comment: Isn't this 27 characters (or bytes)?

Comment: One PETSCII character on Commodore 8-bit machines is equal to 1 byte, but Commodore BASIC, like many early Microsoft BASIC variants is tokenised.

Comment: A more precise answer is that it is difficult to make a byte count for my entry here as it is a special kind of program that runs in direct mode, i.e., it is run immediately after you enter this and press the RETURN key. It is not stored in BASIC memory, unlike BASIC programs which are written with line numbers, and may be executed with the RUN command.

Answer (score 1):

## [Deadfish~](https://github.com/TryItOnline/deadfish-), 27 bytes

```
iisiiiis{ic}ici{ic}icicicic
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0lNTEnLLM7Q/f8/M7M4EwiKqzOTazOTM6EUGP7/DwA)

My first Deadfish~ answer, I don't know if it could be improved.

**How does it work?**

```
ii                             accumulator: 2
  s                            accumulator: 4
   iiii                        accumulator: 8
       s                       accumulator: 64
        {ic}                   accumatator: [65, 75] ('A' -> 'J')
            ic                 accumulator: 76 ('K')
              i                accumulator: 77
               {ic}            accumulator: [78, 88] ('M' -> 'V')
                   icicicic    accumulator: [89, 92] ('X' -> 'Z')
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>47</s> 46 bytes

```python
for i in range(65,90):print(end=chr(i+(i>75)))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/Py2/SCFTITNPoSgxLz1Vw8xUx9JA06qgKDOvRCM1L8U2OaNII1NbI9PO3FRTU/P/fwA)

Yet another boring loop in Python 3 :)

Answer (score 1):

## [Nibbles](http://golfscript.com/nibbles/index.html), 17 nibbles (8.5 bytes)

```
-.,26ch+64$"L"
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m708LzMpKSe1eMGCpaUlaboW63T1dIzMkjO0zUxUlHyUIIJQOZgaAA)

### Explanation

```
  ,26          # for i in range [1-26]
       +64$    #  add 64 to i
     ch        #  convert i to char
-.         "L" # concat all and remove "L"
               # (implicitly print entire string)
```

Alternately, `-.,26ch+96$"l"` works for lowercase and has the same score.

Answer (score 0):

## [Lua](https://www.lua.org/), 139 bytes

```lua
p,c,l=io.write,string.char,{}for i=65,90 do if i~=76 then l[#l+1]=i end end for j=1,#l do p(c(l[j]))end p"\n"for k=1,#l do p(c(l[k]+32))end
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XcqxDoIwEIDhV7nAAuFCRCPG4Z4EO5BS5ODSNrXGweir15TR4Z/@T55jSh41CrFrX4GjwUcMbO@tXsaA78/sAjD1Z7weYHLAM/CXLj3ExViQoZSmU8Rg7LSX@UodlpK1r3Qlw6rqOj9f3GyRwfYHNtWcjrtJ6Qc)

### Explanation

Lua allows us to reference functions, similar to pointers in C and C++. This means we can rename the `io.write` and `string.char` functions to `p` and `c`. On the same line, we also create an empty table.

```lua
p, c, l = io.write, string.char, {}
```

Next we need to populate our `l` table with the ASCII codes of `A` through `Z`, making sure to skip ASCII code 76 that represents an L.

To insert an element into a Lua table, we could use `table.insert`, but that would be quite long. So we get the length of `l` using `#l`, add 1 to the length, and place the ASCII code into the new index.

```lua
for i=65,90 do
    if i ~= 76 then
        l[#l + 1] = i
    end
end
```

Once that's done, we then start looping over the table to print the characters. For this explanation, I'll expand `p` and `c` to show the function names.

The first loop will print the upper-case letters. Then we add a new line. Then we start another loop to print out the lower-case letters, that is +32 to our `l` ASCII table.

```lua
for j=1,#l do
    io.write(string.char(l[j]))
end
io.write"\n"
for k=1,#l do
    io.write(string.char(l[k] + 32))
end
```

Comment: note that you're only supposed to print one of the strings. you can include the other program in your post though

Comment: also unfortunately it seems like the naive approach might be the shortest: [32](https://tio.run/##yylN/P@/oCgzr0QpMSk5JTUtPSMzKzs3L7@gsKi4pLSsvKKySun/fwA)

Comment: whereas the shortest non-naive approach seems to be [55](https://tio.run/##yylN/P8/Lb9IIdPWzFTHwlIhJV8hM1@vvCizJFVDQ0lJUy85I7FII9PO3FQhMS9FIVPbEKRYUzM1L@X/fwA)

Answer (score 0):

## [MathGolf](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/math_golf.txt), 4 [bytes](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/code_page.py)

```
▄'l-
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##y00syUjPz0n7///RtBb1HN3//wE)

**Explanation:**

```python
▄     # Push the lowercase alphabet
 'l- '# Remove the "l"
      # (after which the entire stack is output implicitly as result)
```